# Passing pointer from C to Java becomes NULL

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm working on an Android app for x86 that requires some integration with C. I've been using swig/JNI to do the trick, and things have been running smoothly for the most part. However, pointers have been giving me some errors.

My issue is that I am able to successfully reference variable addresses in the emulator (ARM) but on a device (x86), things do not go as well.

Using the example from [this link](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/swig/swig-4/swig/Examples/java/pointer/index.html?txt), I discovered that the address of any allocated variable in C becomes NULL once this address passes over to Java. For example...

**Swig-generated JNI:**

```
SWIGEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_exampleJNI_new_1intp(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls) {
  jlong jresult = 0 ;
  int *result = 0 ;
  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  result = (int *)new_intp();
  LOGI("Result is %x", result);
  *(int **)&jresult = result; 
  LOGI("JResult is %x", jresult);
  return jresult;
}
```

**Source file containing new_intp():**

```
static int *new_intp() {
  return (int *) calloc(1,sizeof(int));
}
```

I have print statements checking the value of the address as it originates in C and passes over to Java. In new_intp(), the new variable is allocated a good looking address, but once this value returns to JNI and gets cast as a jlong, it turns to NULL.

In other words, `*(int **)&jresult = result;`causes jresult to be 0.

Why does this happen? Is there some particularity of x86 that disallows JNI to work with pointers? Or is it because I'm testing it on a physical device rather than an emulator?

Regards

Comment: Ouch, do you have to call it `this`? That's a reserved keyword in both Java and C++ I believe.

Comment: In C, it isn't. It's probably not best habit to give any variable that name though. Going to edit that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was confused by your question title. Is this a C or a C++ question, and can we tag it appropriately?

Comment: Are you aware that jlong is a 64-bit type?

Comment: Yep, I think I understand that addresses come back to Java as longs, which are 64 bits long.

Comment: Well, have you used print/log statements to verify that the value *after* the cast is valid?  Can you add the java code that attempts to make use of (or debug log) the return value?

Comment: I've added the print statements to the swig JNI section of my code. "Result" gets a valid value, but "jresult" prints out 0.

Comment: @digitalmouse12 - If the C code is showing that jresult is zero, then you've got a problem **(likely with pointer type abuse)** in the C code, not a problem in the jni connection between C and java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like it could be an endianness issue.

```
*(int **)&jresult = result;
```

If `int` is 32 bits, and `jresult` is 64 bits, then on a big-endian architecture this could give unexpected results.

`&jresult` is a pointer to a 64-bit value, so if you cast it to a pointer to a 32-bit value, then you're pointing at the lower-addressed of the two constituent 32-bit words. In a big-endian system this will be the most significant word. So after writing a 32-bit word to the most significant end of the 64-bit value, you get a 64-bit value which is 2^32 times bigger than what you expect.

If your `LOGI` call is treating the parameter as a 32-bit int, and implicitly down-casting it from a 64-bit value, then it will give 0.

Can you see if this works instead?

```
jresult = (jlong) result;
```

Comment: @digitalmouse12 perhaps some part of the system doesn't know it's supposed to be little endian - remember x86 android is not official.  Try dumping out the raw value of jresult (the pointer, not its target) from memory byte-by-byte and see if there is a difference between the direct assignment case and the pointer hackery case.  When I do this on 32 bit desktop linux, I don't get a difference, but that's not your target system.

Comment: @Graham Borland: actually this is a [pointer-aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) issue.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, this is a [pointer-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) issue.  SWIG is using old-school C pointer techniques which don't work in newer GCCs when optimization is on.  Buried in the SWIG docs it specifically [says what to do](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java_compiling_dynamic):

> **Important**
>
> If you are going to use optimisations turned on with gcc
>   (for example -O2), ensure you also compile with -fno-strict-aliasing.
>   The GCC optimisations have become more aggressive from gcc-4.0 onwards
>   and will result in code that fails with strict aliasing optimisations
>   turned on. See the [C/C++ to Java typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java_typemaps_c_to_java_types) section for more details.