# overriding SWIG casting

Tags: android, java-native-interface, swig

It seems that SWIG pointer-casting [is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753241/passing-pointer-from-c-to-java-becomes-null):

```
*(int **)&jresult = result;   // shenanigans
return jresult;
```

It really should just be

```
jresult= (jlong)result;
```

How can I hook into SWIG to tell it how to cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a typemap.   See doc [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Typemaps.html) for more info.  Probably look something like the code below.

```
%typemap(out) TYPE *
%{ 
  *($&1_ltype)&$result = (jlong)$1; 
%}
```

Comment: Are you being generic or is this the literal typemap?

Comment: Being generic. TYPE should be your type.  What I put should be close.

Comment: I'd need to make a typemap for *every* pointer type? That could get exhaustive.  Surely there's a way to specify a rule for all pointers?

Comment: There aren't that many types.  I edited my solution.  TYPE * should match all pointers.

Comment: There are potentially hundreds of types. All of the basics (int, char, etc), as well as any number of user-defined struct pointers, etc.  For a large library, this could be a pretty big, non-DRY list.

Answer (score 1):

While Frohnzie's answer is technically correct (it's what I asked for, after all), the best solution is not to hack how SWIG does casting, but to pass `-fno-strict-aliasing` to gcc.

Buried in the SWIG docs it specifically [says what to do](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java_compiling_dynamic):

> **Important**
>
> If you are going to use optimisations turned on with gcc (for example
>   -O2), ensure you also compile with -fno-strict-aliasing. The GCC
>   optimisations have become more aggressive from gcc-4.0 onwards and
>   will result in code that fails with strict aliasing optimisations
>   turned on. See the [C/C++ to Java typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java_typemaps_c_to_java_types) section for more details.