# atof accuracy with double is causing grief

Tags: c, precision, c-standard-library

I have an ascii "15605632.68128593" and I wish to convert
it to a double without losing accuracy

```
double d;
d=(double)atof("15605632.68128593");
printf("%f",d);

printed result is 15605632.681286
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the printf documentation ... "f, F

The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6"

Answer (score 7):

It's likely you're not getting all the trailing decimal places.  Try `printf("%.8f", d)`.

You might also try `sscanf("15605632.68128593", "%lf", &d)` in place of the `atof` call.

It's also not necessary to cast the result of `atof` to `double`. It's already a double.  But the cast does no harm.

Note that - at least about 6 years ago when I looked at this in detail - many `printf` and `scanf` implementations were buggy in the sense that they didn't function as perfect inverses as you'd assume.  Visual C/C++ and gcc both had problems in their native implementations.  [This paper](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~burger/FP-Printing-PLDI96.pdf) is a useful reference.

Cygwin with gcc 4.3.4:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  double x;

  sscanf("15605632.68128593", "%lf", &x);
  printf("%.8f\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

And then:

```
# gcc foo.c
# ./a
15605632.68128593
```

Answer (score 6):

Goal: **Convert "15605632.68128593" to a double without losing accuracy**.

`atof()` accomplished that to best the program could do.  But since `"15605632.68128593"` (a 16-digit number) is not *exactly* representable as a `double` in your `C`, it was approximated to `1.560563268128593080...e+07`.  Thus accuracy was lost, albeit a small loss.

[Typical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) `double` can represent about 2<sup>64</sup> different numbers.  The nearby candidates and OP's string are shown below for reference.

```
 15605632.68128 592893...  previous double
"15605632.68128 593"       code's string 
 15605632.68128 593080...  closest double
 15605632.68128 6          output
```

---

The grief comes when attempting to print, thinking that what printed was the *exact* value of `x`.  Instead the nearby `double` value was printed. Printout is also rounded. Using the `%f` specifier defaults to 6 places to the right of the '.' giving the reported `15605632.681286`, a 14 digit number.

A better way to see all the significant digits for all `double` is to use the `%e` format with `DBL_DIG` or `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`.  `DBL_DIG` is the most number of digits to the right of the '.', in *decimal exponential notation* `%e`, to show all the digits needed to "round-trip" a `double` (string to double to string without a string difference).  Since `%e` always shows 1 digit to the left of '.', the print below shows `1 + DBL_DIG` significant digits.  `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is 17 on my mine and many `C` environments, but it vary.

If you wish to show *all* the significant digits, you need to qualify what is *significant*.  The `nextafter()` function shows the next representable `double`.  So we might want to show at least enough digits to distinguish x and the next x.  I recommend `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`.  [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897395/2410359)

The *exact* value the program used for your `"1.560563268128593e+07"` is `15605632.68128593079745769500732421875`.  There are few situations where you need to see all those digits.  Even is you request lots of digits, at some point, `printf()` just gives you zeros.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <tgmath.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  double x;
  x = atof("15605632.68128593");
  printf("%.*le\n",DBL_DIG, x); // All digits "round-trip" string-to-double-string w/o loss
  printf("%.*le\n",DBL_DIG + 1, x);  // All the significant digit "one-way" double-string
  printf("%.*le\n",DBL_DIG + 1, nextafter(x, 2*x)); // The next representable double
  printf("%.*le\n",DBL_DIG + 3, x);  // What happens with a few more
  printf("%.*le\n",DBL_DIG + 30, x); // What happens if you are a bit loony
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
1.560563268128593e+07
1.5605632681285931e+07
1.5605632681285933e+07
1.560563268128593080e+07
1.560563268128593079745769500732421875000000000e+07
```

Comment: Yes it was simply a print issue - but it caused me a lot of problems.. thanks

Comment: d=atof("15605632.68128593"); this should be   x=atof("15605632.68128593")

Comment: @alirezasanaee Thanks - Post amended

Answer (score 1):

`double` does not have that much precision. It can only round-trip 15 (`DBL_DIG` from `float.h`) decimal places from decimal string to `double` back to decimal string.

**Edit:** While, in general, my claim is true, it doesn't seem to be your problem here. While there exist 16-decimal-place numbers which can't be round-tripped, this particular input can.