# Using printf to give the output as precise as the input?

Tags: c, printf

I want to write a code where output will be as precise as the input. Consider if I executed

```
scanf("%f", &n);
printf("%f", n);
```

And if I give `1.2` as an input, it should output `1.2` but it outputs `1.200000`. It should be same with integers too, if I give `9` as input, it should only output `9`, not `9.00`. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: One method is to store them as strings. For calculations, just use atof to convert them.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : `%g` may chose **e-notation** format in some case.

Comment: @MadHatter i know that. But pointed out that valuable.,

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : OK!! I pointed that out because I thought OP may not want to print that way. Anyways, that is surely valuable. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP does not specify how to handle an input like "9.00".  I assume OP would like to see "9.00" printed and not "9" as the input gave a tenths and hundredths place.

One needs to read the number first as a string so it can be later assessed for precision.   The number and its precision need separate variables.  A structure would be recommended as in @bgamlath.

Parse the string with `sscanf()` or `atof()`.
Parse the string for the location of `'.'`.

```
int VikasRead(float *value, int *precision) {
  char buf[100];
  *precision = 0;
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) return EOF;
  int end;
  int retval = sscanf(buf, "%f%n", value, &end);
  char * dp = strchr(buf, '.');
  if (dp != NULL && retval == 1) {
    *precision = &buf[end] - dp;
  }
  return retval;
}

int VikasWrite(float value, int precision) {
  int retval;
  if (precision > 1) {
    // Note: printf("%.*f\n", 0, value) is UB.
    retval = printf("%.*f\n", precision - 1, value);  // 1.234
  }
  else if (precision == 0) {;
    retval = printf("%.0f\n", value);  // 123
    }
  else {
    retval = printf("%#.0f\n", value); // 123.
  }
  return retval;
}

void VikasTest(void) {
  float value;
  int precision;
  while (VikasRead(&value, &precision) == 1) {
    VikasWrite(value, precision);
  }
}
```

Exponential inputs like `1.23e56` complicates the process but the approach is still the same.  Need to additionally look for an `'e'` or `'E'`.

Some locales use a `','` as a decimal point further complicating matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try using width specifiers:

`printf("%.1f", n);`

Read [this](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output) for more details.

However, a point to note: For `float` and `double`: Due to precision limitations, you may not get `1.2` printed as `1.2000` or even `1.2`, it may become `1.1996...` something like that.

Well, that is completely different topic, and is well discussed on SO, you can try searching for the same on internet or here on SO.

UPDATE:
For variable precision, you can use `printf("%*f", <width>, <float number>);`. More Details [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store all user inputs as they are. Using `char` pointers and `gets()` or `scanf("%s", ...)`.

If you want to use them in calculations as well, use [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) to convert.

Additionaly, you can use a struct to store both the input representation and the numerical value.

```
stract Number{
 float val;
 char * representaion; // or only precision if you like.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the format specifier `%0.7g` as the maximum precision of `float` is 7 digits

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numberLenght(float d);

int main(void)
{
    float d;
    printf("input: ");
    scanf("%f", &d);
    printf("your input was: %0.7g\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

*For `double` use `%0.16g` (maximum precision of `double` is 16 digits)*

Comment: Where does "maximum precision of float is 7 digits" and "maximum precision of double is 16 digits" derive?  Surely not the C spec.  The C spec §5.2.4.2.2 has minimal precision for a `float` and `double` of 6 and 10 digits, but there are not specified limits to the maximum precision.  Consider [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specificer-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value/19897395#19897395)