# Exporting float from blender and reading in c wrong value

Tags: python, c

I am writing float values from Blender using python, then read in C. 
For some values I get 0.
If I replace that values with numbers like 2.3 or other random numbers It works. 
I am using `struct.pack("<ffff")` to write them.

Here is example value which doesn't work:

```
-8.881784197001252e-16, -1.700029006457271e-15, 6.106226635438361e-16, 1.0
```

When I opened file in hex editor I found correct number written `-8.88178E-16`

How can I read correct value?

Here is python sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import struct

f = open("test.f", "wb")

f.write(struct.pack("<f", -8.881784197001252e-16))
f.write(struct.pack("<f", 123.0324))
```

Then here is C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen("test.f", "rb");
    float test = 0;

    fread(&test, sizeof(float), 1, file);
    printf("a ='%f'\n", test);

    fread(&test, sizeof(float), 1, file);
    printf("b ='%f'\n", test);

    return 0;
}
```

C output that I get is:

```
a ='-0.000000'
b ='123.032402'
```

Comment: I don't see the problem here? Unless it's that Python is printing too many digits.

Comment: Problem is that most of values read are correct but this last few are not,

Comment: if I write `struct.pack("<f", 0.5)` it works, but if I put `struct.pack("<f", -8.881784197001252e-16)` I read 0 in C.

Comment: How are you reading them in C?

Comment: I am using `fread(rotations, sizeof(float), 4, file)`. Also tried one by one and same results.

Comment: Can you please post the simplest *complete* example of Python code and C code that demonstrates the behavior you're seeing? While you're at it, start writing all code this way - don't go into it writing the full-featured version. Write the most basic version you can to prove that you can do what you want with your data (aka export a few floats to your C program), then move on to the "real" version.

Comment: Using `printf("a ='%e'\n", test);` will provide more information.  As it stands now everything look OK: `-8.881784197001252e-16` was written and the same number was read back.  The C code was instructed to print the number as a x.xxxxxx number of which '-0.000000' is the best representation.

Comment: @chux when I printed it with %e I got `-8.881784e-16`. Is this number correct and only printf not displaying it properly?

Comment: Yes see updated comment.  Try `printf("a ='%.16e'\n", test);` to print with 16 places after the decimal point.  BTW: The C code _did_ displaying it properly per the format used `"%f"`.

Comment: To see how many decimal places are needed see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value/19897395#19897395

Comment: Thanks chux, that solved problem. Can you add answer or how can I close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP needs to print the numbers read in C using an exponential notation format to clearly see the significant digits.

```
// printf("a ='%f'\n", test);
printf("a ='%e'\n", test);

// or to print with enough distinguishing significance for all float
#include <float.h>
printf("a ='%.*e'\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, test);
```