# Significant digits using a logarithm and a floating point number

Tags: floating-point, logarithm

Related to this question: [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value).

I want to print the significant digits of a number `n` represented using a double `d` as `n = 2^d`. 
Is there a function of `d` which computes the significant digits of `n`? A maximum number (larger than `0`) for the significant digits is also fine, like `DBL_DIG` in `float.h`.

Edit:
I will be doing many additions to `d` such that `2^d` >> MAX_DOUBLE. I suspect therefore the number of significant digits in `n` will be less than the significant digits of `d`. Is this true? By addition I mean (hopefully this makes sense):

Let `n = n1 + n2`, `n1 = 2^d1`, `n2 = 2^d2` then I will perform `d = d1 + d2`, such that `n = 2^d`.

The reason I am using this is because it is nearly impossible to let `d` overflow and I am fine with loosing lots of precision in `n`.

I will be using a function described here: http://buddy.sourceforge.net/manual/group__info_ge551a6cc544c7d50a3d7c7fb7f5f9374.html#ge551a6cc544c7d50a3d7c7fb7f5f9374.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "compute the significant digits of `n`" as distinct from "compute `n`". Do you want to know how many significant digits there are? (It's the same as the number of significant digits of `d`.)

Comment: @Sneftel: I added relevant usage details to the question

Comment: Do you mean `n = n1 * n2`?

Comment: @SimonByrne I don't think so

Comment: What you have doesn't make sense: addition in log space corresponds to multiplication: `2^(d1+d2) = 2^d1 * 2^d2`