# Floating Point Value Changes After Function Return

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm finding my float value has changed after being returned. 
I output the hex value of the float before being returned and then after it gets returned. I expect the HEX output to be identical but they have changed. Can you please explain why this is happening and how do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  typedef int             uint32;
  typedef unsigned char   uint8;
  static const float CONST_FLOAT = 150.36e6;

  uint32 foo( uint8 param ) {
     return 1;
  }

  float get_float( uint8 param )
  {
       float fVal = 0.0;

       fVal = (foo( param )*1.0) / ( 60.0 * CONST_FLOAT );

       printf("fVal = 0x%X\n", fVal);
       printf("fVal = %f\n", fVal);

       return fVal;
  }

  int main(void) {
     float fTest;

     fTest = get_float(1);

     printf("fTest = 0x%X\n",fTest);
     printf("fTest = %f\n",fTest);

     return;
  }
```

OUTPUT: 
fVal = 0x6A96C728
fVal = 0.000000

fTest = 0x9AAF9000
fTest = 0.000000

I expect the fVal displayed in Hex format to be the same as fTest in Hex but they turned out different why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot print a `float` value with the `"%x"` specifier. It's undefined behavior, and your program is obviously behaving accordingly.

This is from the C11 draft 1570,

> **7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function**
>
> 8. The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
>    **`o,u,x,X`**
>
>    The **unsigned int** argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned
>      decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X) in the style dddd; the
>      letters abcdef are used for x conversion and the letters ABCDEF for X
>      conversion. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear;
>      if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is expanded|
>      with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting a
>      zero value with a precision of zero is no characters.
>      ?
> 9. If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. 282) **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: How do I dump the hex representation of the floating point value? ie. what it looks like in memory.

Comment: @user1144251 Try `printf("fTest = %a\n",fTest);` to print in "hexadecimal floating-point".

Comment: @chux I have never used the `a` specifier, but your are absolutely right, just read it in the draft pdf.

Comment: @chux interesting! `fTest` is a rather small number and the `%a` format reveals more than the unqualified `%f`does.

Comment: @Weather Vane for more detail on revealing more: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359