# Get printf to print all float digits

Tags: c, printf

I'm confused about the behavior of `printf("%f", M_PI)`. It prints out `3.141593`, but `M_PI` is `3.14159265358979323846264338327950288`. Why does printf do this, and how can I get it to print out the whole float. I'm aware of the `%1.2f` format specifiers, but if I use them then I get a bunch of unused 0s and the output is ugly. I want the entire precision of the float, but not anything extra.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value

Comment: Once a piece of text is converted to a float or double, "all" the digits is no longer a meaningful concept. There's no way for the computer to know, for example, that it converted "3.14" or "3.14000000000000000275", and they both happened to produce the same internal representation. You'll simply have to pick the number of digits appropriate to your task, based on what you know about the precision of the numbers involved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does printf do this, and how can I get it to print out the whole
>   float.

By default, the `printf()` function takes precision of `6` for `%f` and `%F` format specifiers. From C11 (N1570) `§7.21.6.1/p8` *The fprintf function* (emphasis mine going forward):

> If the precision is missing, **it is taken as 6**; if the precision is
>   zero and the # flag is not specified, no decimal-point character
>   appears. If a decimal-point character appears, at least one digit
>   appears before it. The **value is rounded** to the appropriate number
>   of digits.

Thus call is just equivalent to:

```
printf("%.6f", M_PI);
```

The is nothing like "whole float", at least not directly as you think. The `double` objects are likely to be stored in binary [IEEE-754 double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) representation. You can see the exact representation using `%a` or `%A` format specifier, that prints it as hexadecimal float. For instance:

```
printf("%a", M_PI);
```

outputs it as:

```
0x1.921fb54442d18p+1
```

which you can think as "whole float".

If all what you need is "longest decimal approximation", that makes sense, then use `DBL_DIG` from `<float.h>` header. C11 5.2.4.2.2/p11 C*haracteristics of floating types* :

> number of decimal digits, q, such that any floating-point number with
>   q decimal digits **can be rounded into a floating-point** number with p
>   radix b digits and back again without change to the q decimal digits

For instance:

```
printf("%.*f", DBL_DIG-1, M_PI);
```

may print:

```
3.14159265358979
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf` to print a float to a string with an overkill display precision and then use a function to trim 0s before passing the string to `printf` using `%s` to display it. Proof of concept:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void trim_zeros(char *x){
    int i;
    i = strlen(x)-1;
    while(i > 0 && x[i] == '0') x[i--] = '\0';
}

int main(void){
    char s1[100];
    char s2[100];
    sprintf(s1,"%1.20f",23.01);
    sprintf(s2,"%1.20f",M_PI);
    trim_zeros(s1);
    trim_zeros(s2);
    printf("s1 = %s, s2 = %s\n",s1,s2);
    //vs:
    printf("s1 = %1.20f, s2 = %1.20f\n",23.01,M_PI);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
s1 = 23.010000000000002, s2 = 3.1415926535897931
s1 = 23.01000000000000200000, s2 = 3.14159265358979310000
```

This illustrates that this approach probably isn't quite what you want. Rather than simply trimming zeros you might want to truncate if the number of consecutive zeros in the decimal part exceeds a certain length (which could be passed as a parameter to `trim_zeros`. Also — you might want to make sure that 23.0 displays as 23.0 rather than 23. (so maybe keep one zero after a decimal place). This is mostly proof of concept — if you are unhappy with `printf` use `sprintf` then massage the result.

Answer (score 1):

Once a piece of text is converted to a float or double, "all" the digits is no longer a meaningful concept. There's no way for the computer to know, for example, that it converted "3.14" or "3.14000000000000000275", and they both happened to produce the same float. You'll simply have to pick the number of digits appropriate to your task, based on what you know about the precision of the numbers involved.

If you want to print as many digits as are likely to be distinctly represented by the format, floats are about 7 digits and doubles are about 15, but that's an approximation.