# Float value input error

Tags: c, floating-point

With working with floating point values I don't know why my C compiler or the System is behaving unexpectedly. Not making it so confusing. Here is a simple program to take float value input and print the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float num;

    printf("Enter float value ");
    scanf("%f", &num);

    printf("Value = %f", num);

    return 0;
}
```

On multiple run of the same code giving me different and weird outputs. Here are some sample runs.

Sample Run #1 **Correct Output**

> Enter float value 12.0312
>   Value = 12.031200

Sample Run #2 **Incorrect and unexpected output**

> Enter float value 324.123
>   Value = 324.122986

Sample Run #3 **Incorrect and unexpected output**

> Enter float value 945.1234
>   Value = 945.123413

I don't know why the system is adding some garbage values at the end. I am using GNU GCC compiler in code::blocks.

Comment: The system is not "adding garbage values". Floating-point representations are inherently imprecise (they don't represent real numbers, they represent a subset of rational numbers.)

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Thanks everyone for making it clear. And for the link. Here is what I found the correct answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken. If in case anyone else has this question this link can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `float` cannot represent every conceivable number exactly.  It has limitations.  The closest `float` to `"324.123"` is `324.122986...`

If you need more precision, use `double`, but even that has its limits too.

A `float` will be correct (match similarly limited input) to at least `FLT_DIG` *significant* digits.  To print a number to `FLT_DIG` significant digits use:

```
printf("%.*e", FLT_DIG - 1, num);
```

---

`FLT_DIG` is at least 6.

> number of decimal digits, q, such that any floating-point number with q decimal digits can be rounded into a floating-point number with p radix b digits and back again without change to the q decimal digits,  ... C11dr §5.2.4.2.2 11

Comment: Is there a C equivalent of [`std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10)?

Comment: @legends2k  Yes.  It appears  `max_digits10` is like `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG/DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` and `digits10` is like `FLT_DIG/DBL_DIG`.

Comment: C11 seems to only have a [DECIMAL_DIG](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits). However, one can define a macro if required, so should be fine, I guess.

Comment: @legends2k   C11 Has all: `DECIMAL_DIG` and `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG  DBL_DECIMAL_DIG  LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG`, C99 only has  `DECIMAL_DIG`. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19897395/2410359 for a sample macro

Comment: Good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Value = %f", num);
```

It will add some value if like :
Enter float value 945.1234
Value = 945.123413

because float value always print a 6 digit after the decimal point

to avoid this you can use the statement like : 
    printf("Value = %.3f", num);

This Will Give You A desire output as you want 
it will print only three number after the decimal point 
you can set as per your requirement like 
    "%.2f" ->for 2 number after the decimal
    "%.3f" ->for 3 number after the decimal
    "%.4f" ->for 4 number after the decimal