# How to keep 9 points of precision with double in C

Tags: c, double, floating-accuracy

I've been reading about the issues with floating point precision in C. I need 9 points  of precision but as we can see this isn't working:

```
double d_lower = 0.123456789;
double d_upper = 123456789.0;
d_upper = d_upper + d_lower;
printf("d_upper: %.11f\n", d_upper);
// Outputs: d_upper: 123456789.12345679104
// Desired: 123456789.123456789
```

There are various posts about WHY this is happening on SO, such as these:
[Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)
[Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

But I can't find any infomration on how to solve this problem? Is there a way to work around it? I need 9 points of accuracy, other people must have the same problem. Is it possible to make a union value that achieves this maybe?

My C skills are fairly basic so I can understand the problem but I can't see how to resolve it or work around it.

Comment: In C, `double` specifies at least 10 decimal digits of _significance_.  (most systems have 15+).  If you want to maintain numbers like 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.123456789, your code should use an arbitrary precision math library. I really think though, you are asking to solve the wrong sub-problem "need 9 points of precision".   Suggest posting the higher level issue.  [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359) may help.

Comment: So thanks I guess for the link to the other post, I can edit my original post with the following if that will help? Perhaps I should have specified, I'm not looking to write cross-platform code I'm coding for Linux only (Debian/Ubuntu), if possible I'd rather not include an extra library either. I was looking for a way to achieve 9 points of precision exactly using doubles. As it goes I only need a total of 18 points of "significance", 9 digitals before the decimal place and 9 digitis after. This is something that on any 64 byte system I would assume (as a C novice) would be fairly trivial.

Comment: You have your answer.  Do all your math with `int64_t` (or `long long`) except for I/O.  Read "123456789.123456789" into `long double ld`, and covert to `int64_t y = roundl(ld*1000000000.0)`.  To print, `printf("%.9Lf", y/1000000000.0L)`.  Typical `double` cannot maintain 18 decimal digits on linear precision.  Typical `long double` can.

Comment: @chux I see, so for my small-ish precision requirements a `long long` and `long double` will suffice. Thank you very much

Comment: `long long`, by spec., handles at least +/-9e18 (your 18 digit requirement).  `long double` _very likely_ handles a similar range and more - it certainly handles at least 10 digits.