# Long double not giving the required precision

Tags: c++, c, file, floating-accuracy

I am reading from a file which has values to a precision of 7 digits in the terms of exponential values

> 4.81591e-007
>
> 5.17968e-007
>
> 5.03954e-008
>
> -8.30735e-007

Though the values I am getting is with only a 5 point precision

> 0.000000
>
> 0.000001
>
> 0.000000
>
> -0.000001
>
> -0.000002

The code is as follows and is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<utility> 
#include<algorithm>
#include<map>
#include<cmath>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<queue>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    FILE *fp2;
    fp2=fopen("output","w");
    int i=0;
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("sruthi_DATA_.txt");
    vector<long double>numberlist;
    long double number;
    while(myFile >> number){    //
            numberlist.push_back(number);
            i++;
    }
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        cout.precision(10);
        cout<<numberlist[j]<<fixed<<endl;
        fprintf(fp2,"%Lf\n",numberlist[j]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: because `%Lf` literally means a number with up to six point precision. use standard `%f` instead

Comment: This is using C function `frpintf()` so added `C` to get the appropriate audience.

Comment: Well, that is for writing into the file. When i am printing into the terminal its giving the same value.

Comment: Try `%Lg` or `%.20Lg` instead of `%Lf` in `fprintf` - does this help?

Comment: If you read a scientific notation number but write a fixed point one, this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Also, maybe you should clarify what you expected to get. I mean, literally write which output you want to get ([edit] your question).

Comment: Is the result displayed the result of 'cout' or the file 'output' ?

Comment: I think '%Lg' works! Thanks :) What does it specify though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the number in `C` in exponential notation (scientific) with 5 places after the decimal point use `"%e"`.

```
fprintf(fp2,"%.5Le\n",numberlist[j]);
fprintf(fp2,"%.*Le\n", 5, numberlist[j]);
fprintf(fp2,"%.Le\n",numberlist[j]);  // If not precision give, defaults to 6.
```

To see a FP value in [Printf width specifier to maintain precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359) use

```
#include <float.h>

fprintf(fp2,"%.*Le\n", LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, numberlist[j]);
// or simply in hexadecimal notation
fprintf(fp2,"%.*La\n", numberlist[j]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try printing the values as `fixed`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

```
 std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10) << value << "\n";
```

Definition:

```
 fixed:       the value is represented with exactly as many digits in
              the decimal part as specified by the precision field
              (precision) and with no exponent part.

 scientific:  as many decimal digits as the precision field
              (precision). Finally, this notation always includes an
              exponential part consisting on the letter e followed by
              an optional sign and three exponential digits.
```

For printing in C:

```
  fprintf(fp2, "%.10f\n", value);
```

The definition of the format specifier is:

```
  %[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier

  Precision: For a, A, e, E, f and F specifiers: this is the number
             of digits to be printed after the decimal point.
```

So to achieve the same format in C++ as you get with C(%f) you need to use `std::fixed`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `fprintf` to print ten digits after the dot you have to write `%.10f` in the formatting string. The precision of `cout` does not influence `fprintf`.

And you have to pass the IO manipulator `fixed` to `cout` before the numbers for it to take effect. Otherwise the first number you print will not be in fixed precition.

```
cout << fixed << numberlist[j] << endl;
```