# When long-double calculator loses its precision?

Tags: c, math, long-double

My task was to write a code for a calculator that operates on `long double`. It turns out that after the certain point the calculator loses precision. For example it computes correctly `9999999 ^ 2`, but as far as `99999999 ^ 2` it yields the result, which is 1 bigger than it should be. I've already read something about the float precision, but all questions are concerned with decimals. I know that one can fix it by using the gmp library, but my question is:

> Is there any other way to tackle this problem?
>   How to calculate/show the point to which a long double calculator is accurate?

**main.c**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[100];
    char key[] = "exit";

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        switch (argv[1][1])
        {
            case 'V': case 'v':
                setValid(1);
                break;
            case 'E': case 'e':
                setError(1);
                break;
            default:
                setValid(1);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        setValid(1);

    while (gets(str) != NULL && strcmp(key, str) != 0)
    {
        if (calcFilter(str));
        else
            printf("expression error!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**evalexpression.c**

```
static long double f1, f2;
static char op;

int isValidExpression(const char *str)
{
    int res;
    char ops[10];

    res = sscanf(str, "%Lf %s %Lf", &f1, ops, &f2);

    if (res == 3 && (ops[0] == '+' || ops[0] == '*' || ops[0] == '-' ||
        ops[0] == '/' || ops[0] == '^'))
    {
        op = ops[0];
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;

long double getExprValue(void)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            return (f1+f2);
        case '*':
            return (f1*f2);
        case '-':
            return (f1-f2);
        case '/':
            return (f1/f2);
        case '^':
            return (pow(f1, f2));
        default:
            perror("something went wrong");
            return 0;
    }
}
```

**calcfilter.c**

```
static int errorsw = 0, validsw = 0;

int calcFilter(const char *str)
{
    if (validsw == 1 && isValidExpression(str))
    {
        printf("%s = %Lf\n", str, getExprValue());
        return 1;
    }
    else if (errorsw == 1 && !isValidExpression(str))
    {
        printf("%s\n", str);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (errorsw)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void setError(int mode)
{
    errorsw = mode;
}

void setValid(int mode)
{
    validsw = mode;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to accurately handle values that large? If so I'd google search arbitrary precision arithmetic. It's slower but will give you exact results

Comment: As far as determining the accuracy of long double values you could look for information in the limits.h header file. Wikipedia also helps with understanding the format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format

Comment: On the bed-post overnight.

Comment: please use length-checking input instead of `gets` , and `%s` in scanf

Answer (score 3):

Using `pow(f1, f2)` is counter-productive as that converts the parameters to `double` before calling `pow()` and explains OP's woes.  `double` typically has trouble beginning with 16 decimal digts as in OP's case.  Recommend `powl()`

```
// return (pow(f1, f2));
return (powl(f1, f2));
```

---

Other notes:

`long double` can precisely encode numbers with `LDBL_DIG` decimal digits.  That is at least 10 and likely 18+ on your machine.

`long double`, when printed needs `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits of output to distinguish that number from all other `long double`.  To see all the significance, avoid using `%Lf` when trying to determine precision related issues.

```
printf("%.*Le", LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, x);   // "%Le"
```

See also [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)

---

[edit]  When does floating point lose precision?

`* /` is easy.   As long the result is not so small (sub-normal) or overflows, the answer should be expected to be with 0.5 ULP ([unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)).

`+ -` When the result is further away from zero, again lose up to 0.5 ULP.  But when there is cancellation like `1.0 - 0.9999999...`, nearly all precision can be lost.

`z=pow(x,y)`  can be very imprecise when `z` is a large number and the function poorly written such as when the math identity is simplistically used: `z = exp(log(x)*y)`.  Otherwise a good `pow()` result will be within 1.0 ULP.

---

[@M.M comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322932/when-long-double-calculator-loses-its-precision/34323696#comment56389307_34323696) that an alternative to using `powl()` is to `#include <tgmath.h>` for automatic correct selection of many `<math.h>` functions.

Comment: if `#include <tgmath.h>` is present then it ought to select the right "overload" for `pow(`