# How to printf real digit of float in printf

Tags: c

for instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    my_printf("%f\n", 1.233239208938208);
    my_printf("%f\n", 1.23);
    return (0);
};
```

I hope output is

```
1.233239208938208
1.23
```

How should I do?

Comment: You can print (say) 2 decimal places like this `printf("%.2f\n", 1.23);`

Comment: Your question is not so clear... what are you asking exactly?

Comment: I think what you want is for the computer not to print any leading zeroes, without having to manually set precision.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `my_printf()` works like `printf()`, include the precision as commneted by [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881537/how-to-printf-real-digit-of-float-in-printf/34882242#comment57501333_34881537).  If the precision field is not specified, 6 is used.

```
int main(void) {
  printf("%f\n", 1.233239208938208);
  printf("%f\n", 1.23);
  printf("%.*f\n", 15, 1.233239208938208);
  printf("%.*f\n", 2, 1.23);
  printf("%.15f\n", 1.233239208938208);
  printf("%.2f\n", 1.23);
  // Alternatively use %g which avoids trailing zeros
  printf("%.16g\n", 1.233239208938208);
  printf("%.16g\n", 1.23);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1.233239
1.230000
1.233239208938208
1.23
1.233239208938208
1.23
1.233239208938208
1.23
```

When printing `double` to high precision,  consider that issues begin past `DBL_DIG` places.
See [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)

---

Further detail: `1.23` is a `double`.  Typical `double`, internally, do not take on the *exact* value as expressed in decimal text due to binary floating point representation.  Instead, the closest `double` to `1.23` may be *exactly* `1.229999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875`.