# convert char * to double,without losing precision in c

Tags: c, char, strtod

I need some help. I have to **convert and STORE a char * into a double or long double** without losing precision.

Indeed, i tried to use **strtold** and **atof** methods (also **strtold**), but these methods are rounding the value.

For example:

```
char * key  ="39.7519707";

double ld =strtod((char*)key,NULL);

printf("%lf", ld);
```

prints : 39.751971

but `printf("%6.7f",ld)` gives me the right value but I couldn't store into a variable.

Comment: `but I couldn't store into a variable.`...what is that?

Comment: i need to convert it and store it into a double..

Comment: Using `"%f"` is problematic in showing significant digits.  To print a FP value and see its significant digits, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359

Comment: Not losing precision is impossible because `double` typically has only limited number of bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you only need `%f` format specifier to print a `double`.

Then, you're not losing precision by making use of `strtod()`, the output *representation* is the problem with how you use `printf()` with `%f` format specifier.

As per `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, *`fprintf()`*

> [...] If the
>   precision is missing, it is taken as 6;[...]

Next, when you did

```
printf("%6.7f",ld);
```

the precision became 7 and it outputs the value you expect to see.

Comment: First Thanks for your answer.

Oh ok... so what i'm able to undertand is that strtod() gives me the right value but i'm not printing it correctly, right?

Comment: @kuttyV that's pretty much it.

Comment: @kuttyV `strtod()` probably won't give _exactly_ the right value, because most systems use binary floating point, not decimal, but it will be as close as possible.

Comment: @IanAbbott : Oh,so what do you think i can use instead of strtod() ?

Comment: @kuttyV It's not `strtod` that's the problem. It's a fundamental inability to represent most decimal fractions _exactly_ as a binary fraction with a finite number of digits. That's the same problem as not being able to represent 1/3 exactly as a decimal fraction with a finite number of digits.