# Printf big double value with high precision in C

Tags: c

How to print big double value with precision of 10 in C-language (C99) ?

```
double d1 = 1100200300400500600.0000000001;
double d2 = 1100200300400500600.0000000001;
double d3 = d1 + d2;
printf("???", d3);
```

Expect to have output: 2200400600801001200.0000000002

Comment: I tried `%f` and got `2200400600801001216.0000000000`.

Comment: I'd recommend to use an arbitrary precision library.

Comment: `double` in typical environment (64-bit IEEE754) is not capable to store such value with high precision.

Comment: If you ignore the decimal comma until the point where you are about to present the value to the user, everything turns so much easier. Then you can use one of the various "big int" libraries out there.

Comment: Your question mentions “precision of 10” but seems to show that you don't understand what this means. Here is the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: 6 decimal digits of "precision" for `float`, 15 decimal digits for `double`, for an appropriate definition of "precision".

Comment: [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats) 64-bit double-precision floats have a 53-bit mantissa, which is 15.9 decimal digits, so you can only trust the first 15 digits for accuracy. 32-bit single-precision floats have 24-bit fractions, or 7.2 decimal digits.

Comment: The only *exact* string representation of a binary floating-point value is a hexadecimal floating-point form, which requires the `%a` printf format specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an arbitrary precision library for c.

I you're going to store integers, you can use the [`GMP`](https://gmplib.org/).

If you're going to store large floating-point values, I would recommend you to use the [`MPFR`](http://www.mpfr.org/), a library which supports floating-point types. The `MPFR` is based on the `GMP`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check how floating points are stored in C. C99 implements IEEE754. This gives you 11 bits for exponent and 52 bits for mantissa. It's only those 52 bits you can use to represent the number. Exponent tells you where the floating point will be.

**You simply can not store such big number with given precision in double.**

Comment: C99 does not specify IEEE754.  It does support its use.

Comment: @chux: True, but practically every implementation of C99 uses IEEE floats.

Comment: @Peter Šilon: I think you mean that you simply can't store *that many digits* in a double. The number itself is not too big, just the number of digits.

Comment: @David R Tribble The degree of adherence to IEEE754 or other formats is far more a function of the underlying hardware than the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

OP's code is not *exactly* assigning value as perceived.  `double` can only represent a finite set of numbers.  It will use the *closest* representable *double*.  Typically `double` can accurately represent *at least* the first 15 signification decimal digits, or `110020030040050xxxx.xxxx`

`1100200300400500600.0000000001` lies between two `double`:
`1100200300400500480` and
`1100200300400500608`.

```
// Add d1 to the closest representable double.  This turns out to be _exactly
//          1100200300400500608
double d1 = 1100200300400500600.0000000001;
double d2 = 1100200300400500600.0000000001;

// adding those 2 result in the _exact
//          2200400600801001216
double d3 = d1 + d2;

// To print to 10 decimal places
printf("%.10f", d3);
// 2200400600801001216.0000000000
```

---

With typical floating point, to print the value *exactly*, use

```
printf("%a\n", d3);
```

To print a `double` in decimal with [sufficient accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359) to distinguish all `double`, use

```
printf("%.e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, d3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple. I suggest you to use a library like [GMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library). I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, but the answer, as I said, it's not so simple as it seems to be.

Of course, you can code yourself the operations, and it's a good practice (if you want to kill some time). :)