# increase long double accuracy

Tags: c++, c, double

how can I increase accuracy in double.

for example in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    long double a = (long double) 5 / 3;
    printf("%.62LLF", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double`s are only so precise.

Comment: By using an external library.

Comment: By writing a custom cpp compiler or adding some flags to the existing ones.

Comment: you really need more accuracy than a long double ?

Comment: You can't increase accuracy in `double`. Nor any other primitive type for that mater.

Comment: Printing decimal digits of a fraction is a problem completely unrelated to `double`, if that's what you want to do I'm sure there is an appropriate duplicate on this site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printf big double value with high precision in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651574/printf-big-double-value-with-high-precision-in-c)

Comment: Perhaps the more interesting question is why do you need better accuracy?

Comment: Step 1: Use correct print specifier  `printf("%.62LLF", a);` --> `printf("%.62LF", a);`  (one L and enable all compiler warings).  2) Use exponential notation `"%.62Le"`.  3) Use `a` for complete hex output `printf("%La\n", a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating Point Numbers have a limited precision. [Mandatory Reading Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

The [boost.multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) library can give you access to higher precision floating point numbers, whether in the form of `quad` types which simply double the precision of `double`, or in the form of arbitrary precision `rational` numbers. If you're willing to take the time to learn how to install and use that library, you'll be able to improve the precision of your numbers.