# How to change output from binary to ascii?

Tags: c, file

I want to make a small change in one C code,in order to double-check some results.Just few relevant lines

```
 FILE           *f1_out, *f2_out;

/* open files */
if ((f1_out = fopen(vfname, "w")) == (FILE *) NULL)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: Can't open file %s.\n", progname, vfname);
   return (-1);
}
```

Then goes some calculations and

```
yes = fwrite(vel, nxyz*sizeof(float), 1, f1_out);
```

How to change the last line to get the ascii output?

Comment: Why don't you simply replace it with fprintf()?

Comment: Note that if you open file for writing in binary mode, mode argument should be `"wb"`. Also, casting `NULL` with `(FILE *)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `yes = fwrite(vel, nxyz*sizeof(float), 1, f1_out);`, use

```
for(i = 0; i < nxyz; ++i) {
  yes &= (fprintf(f1_out, "%d:\t%f\n", i, vel[i]) > 0);
}
```

Comment: Bitwise AND with the bits from the number of characters written seems like a strange thing to do.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy It is `fprintf(..) > 0`. `fprintf` return negative value on failure. And for float, it must return `> 0` if succesful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `vel` is an array of floats, and your `nxyz` is the number of floats in that array, and that you want the output on the standard output and not on the file you opened:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nxyz; ++i) {
    printf("vel[%d] = %f\n", i, vel[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To see *all* [meaningful digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897395/2410359) in a `float` as text use `printf("%*e", some_precision, some_float)`

```
#include <float.h>
fprintf(f1_out, "%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, *vel);
```