# Can´t convert float or double to char array (sprintf)

Tags: c, printf

```
double d = 3.3;
char str[50];
sprintf(str, " \t%f", d);
USBD_VCOM_SendString(str);
```

Wanted to send the double from my µController to my Computer but str always seams to be empty. Tried it with int too and it worked fine. Also doesn´t work for float.
I´m using a ARM-GCC C Compiler.

Comment: Looks as if floating point number formatting is not implemented in your CRT.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a big problem. Any other ways to convert a float or double to a char array?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, it just _looks_ so. Have a look into the documentation and/or the source code of the CRT whch should be available.

Comment: Check the return value from `sprintf()`; it should report the number of characters written to the string.  It's usually a good idea to use `snprintf()` to ensure no buffer overflow — a value such as 1E+123 will overflow your buffer handily, which is bad news (even if the value is unlikely to occur, which I fully accept).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Using `ptintf` & friends on a MCU is most certainly a bad idea. Similar for using floating point - worse `double`. It often is a signal of bad system design. Use integers as fractional/fixed point or at least `float`.

Comment: Send the value with binary format and use the `printf` family function on PC side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 issues that need to be resolved.

1) Some compilers, even with `*printf()` using floating point specifiers, do **not** include FP support unless code has FP math elsewhere in the code.  Insure code uses FP elsewhere or that the compiler does not have this limitation.

2) Use a buffer and `*printf()` specifier that will not overflow. [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636500/can%c2%b4t-convert-float-or-double-to-char-array-sprintf/38638582#comment64657110_38636500)
`"%e"` rather than `"%f"`is an easy approach to avoid  excessively long strings.

3) Print with [sufficient precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359).

```
#include <float.h>
//       -   d   .       ddddddd             e   -  expo \0  spare
char str[1 + 1 + 1 + (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1) + 1 + 1 + 5 + 1 + 10];
snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%.*e",  DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, d);

USBD_VCOM_SendString(str);
```