# Precise value of double in decimal and floating?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision

`DBL_MAX` is

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260
780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467
546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304
583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881
250404026184124858368.000000
```

But if I do:

```
double a=1234567890123456789.0;
printf("%f",a);
```

> 1234567890123456768.000000

Here the precision is 17 digits.

```
double a=0.1234567890123456789;
printf("%.20f",a);
```

> 0.1234567890123456773

Here also the precision after the floating point is 17 digits:

```
double a=1234567890.1234567890123456789;
printf("%.20f",a);
```

That will generate:

> 1234567890.12345671653747558594

Now, the precision will be 10 digits for decimal + 7 after the floating point which makes 17.

Does that mean that I have only 17 digits to get a precise value for double? If yes, why is the number of digits of DBL_MAX over 300 digits?

Comment: in the standard. `DBL_MAX                                   1E+37` is the minimum requirement. And for the typical  IEC 60559 floating point, it is `DBL_MAX      1.7976931348623157E+308`. Not sure where you got thatvalue, but there always should be some exponential representation for these values. If you got this from some website: Ask them, not us!

Comment: The problem the system cannot talk :/. Anyway what about the precision ?

Comment: How about reading the standard yourself? You don't expect us to paste what the standard says, just to correct some obscure value we don't even know where you got them from, don't you?

Comment: If you don't mind giving me some of your time I will keep it on reading the standard and many things !

Comment: Where does this weird value come from? Who said that DBL_MAX has ~300 digits precision?

Comment: okay guys don't say something I did not say. The value you can generate it by a code as DBL_MAX is a n float.h

Comment: I don't care too much about the value of DBL_MAX more than the precision !

Comment: The representation of numbers is *not decimal*, so it is pretty meaningless to define the precision in terms of decimal numbers, as it will change depending on the number itself.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it very well but surely you got the point try to minimize the decimal part (left part from the floating point) and the precision will be added to the right part.

Comment: Well, that's simplistic. @chux has a good answer (as usual).

Comment: If it is simplistic and a good answer why you did not upvote it then ?! @EugeneSh.

Comment: First of all - I did. Second - simplistic was about your view, not the answer. Third - don't tell people what to do with their votes.

Answer (score 2):

Typical `double` has 15-16 decimal digits of significance - as compared to the next `double`.

All finite `double` have exact values like with OP's `DBL_MAX = 1797693134862315708...`.  Floating point numbers are distributed logarithmically.   So typically there are as many different `double` between 0.5 and 1.0 as there are between 2 and 4.

This distribution means OP's 2nd largest number only matches `DBL_MAX` to first 16 places out of the 300+ digits.  See below.

---

> Does it mean that I have only 17 digits to get a precise value for double ? If yes what is the use of all that number of digits for DBL_MAX more than 300 digit?

`double`, as [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can represent *exactly* about 2**64 different numbers.  `0.1234567890123456789` is not one of them.  The closest `double` is `0.1234567890123456773...`  Notice it matches to at least 15 `(DBL_DIG)` digits.

Usually this means the *exact* value of a `double` is not as important as its relative difference to the next `double`.

The value of `1e300` or `1e-300` is one of *range*, not precision.

---

```
int main(void) {
  printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 2, DBL_MAX);
  printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 2, nextafter(DBL_MAX,0));
  printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 2, nextafter(0, 1));
}
```

Output

```
1.7976931348623157081e+308
1.7976931348623155086e+308
4.9406564584124654418e-324
```

Consider using `printf("%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1, a);` rather than `printf("%.20f",a);` to get a more clear view of the [decimal notation significance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359) of a `double`.  If you are ready for hexadecimal notation, try `printf("%a",a);`

Comment: [You get 15-16 decimal digits](http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/)

Comment: @Rick Regan Yes, I'll go with 15-16.  It depends on the region of FP numbers.  17 is the number of significant digits needed with binary64 to distinctly print all of them.

Answer (score 2):

The commonest system for representing C doubles is IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point. It is a base 2 system. That means the exactly representable numbers have relatively short binary representations - fitting in 64 bits - but not necessarily short decimal representations.

The exact value of the largest finite number is `2^1024 - 2^971` or 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368

That is not very useful information, because of the granularity of the numbers. Consecutive numbers differ by about one part in 10^16.9. For example, the next to largest representable number is 179769313486231550856124328384506240234343437157459335924404872448581845754556114388470639943126220321960804027157371570809852884964511743044087662767600909594331927728237078876188760579532563768698654064825262115771015791463983014857704008123419459386245141723703148097529108423358883457665451722744025579520

You don't need all those digits to distinguish them. If you know you have one of those numbers, seeing the 17 character prefixes 17976931348623157 and 17976931348623155 is enough to tell which.

Library functions that convert double to decimal strings have a problem. How many digits should you print? Here are some of the options:

- Print the exact value. Almost always the wrong thing to do, because you will print a lot of digits that do not convey any useful information.
- Print enough digits to distinguish which double you started with. That is the choice made, for example, for Java's Double.toString. This allows exact recovery of the double from the printed value.
- Print only a fixed number of digits. Makes for tidy reports.

Comment: [I used to think Java's Double.toString worked that way too](http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-doesnt-print-the-shortest-strings-that-round-trip/). For example, try printing 8.41E21.

Comment: @RickRegan So far, I have not encountered a situation in which Double.toString fails to produce enough digits to distinguish the exact value. Your example is a case of it outputting more digits than the shortest possible.

Comment: I was interpreting what you wrote as "Print JUST enough digits". Printing "enough" digits is kind of open-ended though, since that means it can print anything from the shortest to the exact value.