# Function pow() does not work correctly when using big numbers?

Tags: c, floating-point, pow

Please explain why pow() doesn't work for the big number such as 2^63?(if you write a pow function with the prototype of `pow(long long int a, long long int b)` instead of `pow(double a, double b)` it works fine.)

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%.0lf\n" ,pow((double)2,63));
}
```

output:

```
9223372036854775800
```

true answer:

```
9223372036854775808
```

thanks.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] as part of your question.

Comment: Define "does not work correctly", ideally with the REAL output

Comment: Do you know what different types mean?

Comment: What was the _return type_ of your `pow(long long int a, long long int b)` example?

Comment: @chux it is also long long int

Comment: See Wikipedia on [IEEE 754 double precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  The `double` type normally uses 12 bits for the sign and exponent, leaving 52 (effectively 53) bits to store the mantissa.  While 2^63 only has 1 binary bit set, as you divide by 10 repeatedly to create the binary representation, you gradually use more bits, and you can start to run into problems, needing more bits to represent the value left over accurately.  I'm not certain that's the cause, but there are limits to the accuracy of all these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf("%.0lf\n", x);` is not required to print the *exact* value of `(double) x`.

A compliant C compiler/standard C library will generate code that will print about `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` (typically 17), correct *significant* decimal digits.  Other may print more digits correctly.  (Mine printed `9223372036854775808`).  See `<float.h>`

```
// 45678901234567
9223372036854775800 // answer
9223372036854775808 // true answer:
```

---

Extreme example

`DBL_MAX` may have the [*exact* value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38642394/2410359) of

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368
```

Yet many results of `printf("%.0lf\n" ,DBL_MAX);` will report zeros after a certain point

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

OP [later added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981980/function-pow-does-not-work-correctly-when-using-big-numbers/42982212#comment73057233_42981980) that the reference `pow()` function was `long long int pow(long long int a, long long int b)`.  `pow_ll_version(2,63)` would be expected to result in `9223372036854775808`, which is 1 passed many `LLONG_MAX` - certainly undefined behavior.  Let us assume it *wrapped* to `-9223372036854775808`, and was printed with  `printf("%llu\n" , long_long_int_result);` (more UB as mis-matched specifier and type).  This may have given `9223372036854775808` to OP.

`printf()` output of integers is exact, not so with floating point values.

Comment: The **compiler** will not print anything. It is the implementation of the standard library, i.e. the environment.

Answer (score 0):

`pow` works fine. MSVC's `printf` is buggy and truncates the output for floating point.

Comment: Why the downvote? `9223372036854775800` is not a possible value that can be represented in a `double`, so it's obviously not what `pow` returned. The only way it could have appeared is by `printf` printing it wrong, and the only implementation I know with this bug is MSVC's.

Comment: @R..I didn't give you downvote!!

Comment: @FatemehKarimi I didn't downvote either but you could be more helpful than that by updating what compiler/library you are using (whether or not it's MSVC; if so, the version you're using) and how you are compiling, etc.

Comment: NMDV, but printing "...75800" is not buggy, (it is compliant C IMO), as it is weak.  Only rare implementations do not resort to truncation at some point for large values.

Comment: @chux: While it's not forbidden (although POSIX has some fairly restrictive rules on what value must be printed; I don't recall if plain C does too), it still amounts to a quality-of-implementation "bug" in my book. There are multiple good implementations capable of printing the exact value or the correctly-rounded value to the requested precision. Printing zeros after `DECIMAL_DIG` places is just lazy and poor-quality, and MSVC is something of an outlier in doing it that way.