# Convert double value to uint_8 type array

Tags: c, string, floating-point

I'm new to C development. How can convert I `double` values to a `uint_8` type array.

```
double test=1234.642462
```

I want to save as it as

```
uint8_t data[] = {'1','2','3','4','.','6','4','2','4','6','2'};
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use `snprintf`.

Comment: Convert it to a string, then convert the string to `uint8_t`.

Comment: `sprintf(data, "%f", test);`

Comment: You want a C-string or just as array?

Comment: Do you want the result as `int8_t` or `uint8_t`? Because your question mentions both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `snprintf` function like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>    

int8_t data[20];
double test=1234.642462;

snprintf(data, 20, "%f", test);
```

The 20 character limit should be adjusted to the desired precision, since floating point numbers can be very long.

Answer (score 0):

`DBL_MAX` is typically about `179769...(303 more digits).0`.  Usually only the first 17 are consider significant.

`DBL_MIN` is typically about `0.000(303 more zeros)222507...` And again  usually only the first 17 are consider significant.

To convert the entire range of `double` into a non-exponential decimal string showing significant digits can take hundreds of bytes - not a practical approach.

To convert a `double` into a decimal text representation, stored in `char`, `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc., is best done using *exponential* notation with enough, but not excessive amount of significant digits.  Use `*printf()` family with `e`.

```
#include <float.h>
//                     -   d   .       dddd                e   -  expo \0
#define DBL_TEXT_SIZE (1 + 1 + 1 + (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1) + 1 + 1 + 6 + 1)
...
uint8_t data[DBL_TEXT_SIZE];
sprintf(data, "%.e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, test);
```

For more details: See [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)