# What is the difference between DECIMAL_DIG and LDBL_DIG in <float.h>

Tags: c, floating-point

The macro constant `DECIMAL_DIG` is the

> number of decimal digits that can be converted to `long double` and back without losing precision.

The macro constant `LDBL_DIG` is the

> number of decimal digits that can be represented without losing precision for `long double`.

What is the difference between these two definitions? Is there a case where using one over the other could lead to incorrect results?

On my machine, `DECIMAL_DIG == 21`, while `LDBL_DIG == 18`.

Source: [1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)

Comment: Andrew McKinlay: Any more needed to  help with this post?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica None of the answers seem to address the question in the context of the definitions given in the question. They all seem to provide their own definitions for the macros. Are the definitions I quoted wrong or not?

Comment: Andrew, the 2nd definition is wrong. The first is incomplete.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 9):

[Edit Oct 2021]
The next version of [C (C2x or C23)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)) *may* "make `DECIMAL_DIG` obsolescent" per [DR 501](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_501).
I recommend you consider alternatives.

---

> What is the difference between `DECIMAL_DIG` and `LDBL_DIG` (?)

`DECIMAL_DIG` concerns *widest floating point type* to *decimal text* to *widest floating point type* conversions.
`LDBL_DIG` concerns *decimal text* to `long double` to *decimal text*  conversions.

---

First: **Narrow the problem**

`DECIMAL_DIG` (available since C99) applies to the *widest* floating point type.  With C11, 3 type specific macros `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG`, `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`, `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` mean the same thing except they apply to the corresponding type, rather than the *widest* one.

To simplify the problem, let us compare `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` to `LDBL_DIG` as they both deal with the same type: `long double`.

---

*decimal text representation* --> `long double` --> *decimal text representation*.
`LDBL_DIG` is the maximum significant digits of text that in this *round-trip* always result in the same starting value.

`long double` --> *decimal text representation* --> `long double`.
`LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is the number of  significant digits of text needed in this *round-trip* to always result in the same starting  `long double` value.

If the floating point type used a base 10 presentation, `LDBL_DIG` and `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` would have the same value.  Yet most C implementations use a binary base 2 instead of 10: `FLT_RADIX == 2`.

---

The follows avoids a deep mathematical technical explanation.

`long double` can not represent every possible value that *decimal text representation* does. The latter can be `s = "0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"` and common `long double` can not represent that *exactly*.  Converting `s` into `long double` and back to text is not expected to return the same result.

```
char *s = "0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
long double ld = strtold(s, (char **)NULL);
printf("%.40Le\n", ld);
// typical output        v -- different
// 1.2345678901234567890132180073559098332225e-01
```

If we limit text input to `LDBL_DIG` *significant* digits though, code will always succeed for all values of `long double` - round trip successfully.

```
s = "0.123456789012345678";
ld = strtold(s, (char **)NULL);
printf("%d\n%.*Le\n", LDBL_DIG, LDBL_DIG - 1, ld);
// 18
// 1.23456789012345678e-01
```

This post [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359) details the use of `xxx_DECIMAL_DIG` family of macros.  It shows the number of significant digits need to print a floating-point value to text and then convert back to a FP value and always get the same result.

---

Note: `xxx_DECIMAL_DIG >= xxx_DIG`.

`LDBL_DIG - 1` used above rather than `LDBL_DIG` as `%.*Le` prints a leading digit and then the specified precision number of digits.  The total significant digit count should be `LDBL_DIG`.

---

---

Further info to answer [Are the definitions I quoted wrong or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703648/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-dig-and-ldbl-dig-in-float-h?noredirect=1#comment105063306_39703648)

First definition is close, yet not complete.
`LDBL_DIG` refers to text --> `long double` --> text needs.

`LDBL_DIG`

> OP's: "number of decimal digits that can be represented without losing precision for long double."

> C Spec: "number of decimal digits, *q*, such that any floating-point number with *q* decimal digits can be rounded into a floating-point number with *p* radix *b* digits and back again without change to the *q* decimal digits,"
>
> q = floor((p-1)*log<sub>10</sub>b)

With OP's machine, [`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) has p == 64 and b == 2 --> q == 18

Thus a decimal number with up to 18 significant digits, as text, can be converted to a `long double` and then back to an 18 digit number, in *text* and always get the starting text value - for the normal `long double` range.

---

`DECIMAL_DIG`

Second definition is amiss.
`DECIMAL_DIG` refers to `long double` --> *text* --> `long double` needs.
OP's definition speaks of *text* to `long double` to *text*.

> OP's: "number of decimal digits that can be converted to long double and back without losing precision."

> C Spec: "number of decimal digits, *n*, such that any floating-point number in the widest supported floating type with *p<sub>max</sub>* radix *b* digits can be rounded to a floating-point number with *n* decimal digits and back again without change to the value,"
>
> n = ceil(1 + p<sub>max</sub>*log<sub>10</sub>b)

With OP's machine, has p == 64 and b == 2 --> n == 21

Thus `long double`s need to be converted to a decimal numbers with at least 21 significant digits, as text, to be convert back to the same `long double` - for the normal `long double` range.

Comment: Using `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` does not narrow or simplify your answer because `DECIMAL_DIG` and `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` are the same.

Comment: @AndrewMcKinlay Fair point.  The simplification is not having to refer to the _widest type_, but instead `long double` as it provides symmetry with `LDBL_DIG`  Since C11, `DECIMAL_DIG` and `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` are the same given `long double` as the widest type.  In future version, (or today with an implementation provided wide type), wider FP types may become standard, then `DECIMAL_DIG, LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` can differ.

Comment: I didn't get why exactly binary base 2 leads to `LDBL_DIG != LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG`. Also: is binary base 2 always mean that `LDBL_DIG == LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 3` (and so on for other FP types)?

Comment: @pmor  The difference is 2 (like IEEE `double`) or 3 (`float`).  Why 2 or 3? --> Without getting into details, pow(2,2) <= 10/2 <= pow(2,3).  A better answer deserves it own SO question.

Comment: @pmor [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value/19897395#19897395) may help.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica [Question created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449603/why-base-2-leads-to-flt-dig-flt-decimal-dig).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Additional questions created: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449728/base-2-why-decimal-dig-dig-2-or-3), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449894/if-c-standard-allows-double-float-then-why-it-requires-dbl-decimal-dig-and).

Answer (score 5):

They're dealing with opposite round-trip directions.

- `DECIMAL_DIG` is the number of decimal digits you need when converting from the largest floating point type to a decimal string and back to ensure that you get back the same value. (Of course for specific values you may be able to get by with fewer digits, but if you want a number of digits that works for any value, `DECIMAL_DIG` is it.) This is the `long double` -> decimal -> `long double` round trip.
- `LDBL_DIG` is the number of decimal digits that will be reliably preserved when converting from decimal to `long double` and back. (For specific cases, more may be preserved, of course.) This is the decimal -> `long double` -> decimal round trip.

The text you quoted seems misleading and possibly utterly wrong, which is what you should expect from cppreference.com. It's a very bad site for information on C or C++.

Comment: are you aware of another website with information on C?

Comment: Read the (draft, freely available, or purchase the final) standard. You can find it by searching for "n1570".

Comment: So "no". The standard is not nearly enough, by the way, especially when talking about floating-point stuff.

Comment: @Cubbi: The answer to this question can easily be found by a text-search of the standard for `DECIMAL_DIG`. This wiki might also be helpful: http://www.iso-9899.info/

Comment: I agree that the standard defines these macros adequately, although it doesn’t explain them (your description is actually more user-friendly). Neither does cppreference right now,, but as any public wiki, it is subject to what the editors choose to write about. I think every macro from float.h deserves a separate page, with rationale, purpose, use cases and examples, but so does everything else. I edited the wording that was quoted here since it was indeed dumb. Still a long way to doing these macros justice, but several poorly-edited pages don't make the whole thing "bad".

Comment: I want to select your answer because of its brevity and closeness to the standard, but it does not demonstrate incorrect usage as asked in the original question, so it would be unfair to the other answers' authors. It also does not explain how the definitions I quoted in the question are misleading or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**LBDL_DIG**:

> Number of decimal digits that can be rounded into a floating-point and back without change in the number of decimal digits.

and

> Number of decimal digits, q, such that any floating-point number with q decimal digits can be rounded into a floating-point number with p radix b digits and back again without change to the q decimal digits.

[image]

**DECIMAL_DIG**:

> Number of decimal digits that can be rounded into a floating-point type and back again to the same decimal digits, without loss in precision.

and

> Number of decimal digits, n, such that any floating-point number in the widest supported floating type with pmax radix b digits can be rounded to a floating-point number with n decimal digits and back again without change to the value.

[image]

Answering to the OP's question:
They are calculated in a different way. The formulas are attached above and are the reasons to the differences.

[Source1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/) [Source2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/float.h.html) [Useful url](https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/31m0rw/why_is_the_c_programming_languages_macro_decimal/)

Comment: While your first definition quoted for `DECIMAL_DIG` corresponds to my definition, I do not see how it differs the first definition you quote for `LDBL_DIG`. "Number of decimal digits that can be rounded into a floating-point type and back again to the same decimal digits, without loss in precision" and "number of decimal digits that can be rounded into a floating-point and back without change in the number of decimal digits" sound the same to me.