# Why base-2 leads to FLT_DIG != FLT_DECIMAL_DIG?

Tags: c, floating-point, c11

Context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39707410/1778275 :

> If the floating point type used a base 10 presentation, LDBL_DIG and LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG would have the same value.

Question: why base-2 leads to `FLT_DIG != FLT_DECIMAL_DIG`?

The same question goes for prefixes: `DBL_`, `LDBL_`, `FLT16_`.

Comment: This is more a math than a programming question

Comment: The short answer btw is... because 10 isn't an integer power of 2 so for every conversion some precision will be lost