# base-2: why DECIMAL_DIG - DIG == 2 or 3?

Tags: c, floating-point, c11

base-2: why `DECIMAL_DIG - DIG` == 2 or 3?

Examples:

- `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - FLT_DIG == 9 - 6 == 3`
- `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - DBL_DIG == 17 - 15 == 2`
- `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG - LDBL_DIG == 21 - 18 == 3`
- `FLT16_DECIMAL_DIG - FLT16_DIG == 5 - 3 == 2`

Extra: Is it guaranteed that on any given implementation using base-2 this difference will be 2 or 3?

Comment: probably related: [Why do I need 17 significant digits (and not 16) to represent a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6118231/995714), [17 Digits Gets You There, Once You’ve Found Your Way](https://www.exploringbinary.com/17-digits-gets-you-there-once-youve-found-your-way/)

Comment: 2 <= ceil(1+p*log10(2)) - floor((p-1)*log10(2)) <= 3, mainly because log10(2) is an irrational number between 0 and 1, and p is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for base-2 radix, `xxx_DECIMAL_DIG - xxx_DIG` will be 2 or 3.

**Informal proof**

For a floating point type:

- *b* is the base or radix or exponent representation (an integer > 1)
- *p* is the precision (the number of base-*b* digits in the significand) (I assume this is > 1 and rational)

The `xxx_DECIMAL_DIG` values are defined as:

⎰ *p* log<sub>10</sub> *b* — if *b* is a power of 10
⎱ ⌈1 + *p* log<sub>10</sub> *b*⌉ — otherwise

The `xxx_DIG` values are defined as:

⎰ *p* log<sub>10</sub> *b* — if *b* is a power of 10
⎱ ⌊(*p* - 1) log<sub>10</sub> *b*⌋ — otherwise

For *b* = 2, log<sub>10</sub> *b* ≈ 0.301 and is irrational ([proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Logarithm_Base_10_of_2_is_Irrational)).
∴ *p* log<sub>10</sub> 2 is irrational (since *p* is rational and > 1).
∴ ⌈*p* log<sub>10</sub> 2⌉ - ⌊*p* log<sub>10</sub> 2⌋ = 1.
∴ ⌈1 + *p* log<sub>10</sub> 2⌉ - ⌊*p* log<sub>10</sub> 2⌋ = 2. — ①
⌊*p* log<sub>10</sub> 2⌋ - ⌊(*p* - 1) log<sub>10</sub> 2⌋ ∈ {0, 1}. — ② (since 0 < log<sub>10</sub> 2 < 1)
∴ ⌈1 + *p* log<sub>10</sub> 2⌉ - ⌊(*p* - 1) log<sub>10</sub> 2⌋ ∈ {2, 3}. — (from ① and ②) ∎

Comment: FYI: Here is an interesting [DR](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_501) discussing whether `DECIMAL_DIG` can be larger than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Given definitions of `xxx_DECIMAL_DIG` and `xxx_DIG` we have
[2 <= ceil(1+p*log10(2)) - floor((p-1)*log10(2)) <= 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449728/base-2-why-decimal-dig-dig-2-or-3#comment122754941_69449728)
Simplifying:

```
2 <=     ceil(1+p*log10(2)) - floor((p-1)*log10(2)) <= 3
2 <= 1 + ceil(  p*log10(2)) - floor((p-1)*log10(2)) <= 3
let q = p – 1
2 <= 1 + ceil(  (1 + q)   *log10(2)) - floor((p-1)*log10(2)) <= 3
2 <= 1 + ceil(log10(2) + q*log10(2)) - floor(  q  *log10(2)) <= 3
let R = trunc(q*log10(2))
let r = trunc(q*log10(2)) – R, r is [0.0 …1.0)
log10(2) = 0.301…
2 <= (1 + R + ceil(0.301… + r)) – (R + floor(r)) <= 3
2 <=  1     + ceil(0.301… + r)       – floor(r)  <= 3
2 <=  1     + ceil(0.301… + r)       – 0         <= 3
When r <= 1.0 - 0.301…
  2 <= 1 + 1 <= 3
Otherwise r > 1.0 - 0.301…
  2 <= 1 + 2 <= 3
```

---

Even though it is shown that the difference is 2 or 3, I suppose the next questions are why are
`xxx_DECIMAL_DIG`: ceil(1+p*log10(2))
and
`xxx_DIG`: floor((p-1)*log10(2))?

Comment: FYI: Here is an interesting [DR](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_501) discussing whether `DECIMAL_DIG` can be larger than necessary.

Comment: @pmor Looks like `DECIMAL_DIG` is becoming obsolete with C23.  "Major changes in this fifth edition (`__STDC_VERSION__ 202311L`) include:" ... "made the `DECIMAL_DIG` macro obsolescent;"  (DR 501)