# If C standard allows "double == float", then why it requires DBL_DECIMAL_DIG and DBL_DIG >= 10 (and not >=6)?

Tags: c, floating-point, language-lawyer

N2596 working draft — December 11, 2020 ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E):

> The values given in the following list shall be replaced by implementation-defined constant expressions with values that are greater than or equal to those shown:
>
> ```
> #define DBL_MAX                1E+37
> #define FLT_MAX                1E+37
> ```

> The values given in the following list shall be replaced by implementation-defined constant expressions with (positive) values that are less than or equal to those shown:
>
> ```
> #define DBL_MIN                1E-37
> #define FLT_MIN                1E-37
> ```

> The values given in the following list shall be replaced by implementation-defined constant expressions that are greater or equal in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same
> sign:
>
> ```
> #define DBL_DECIMAL_DIG        10
> #define DBL_DIG                10
> #define FLT_DECIMAL_DIG        6
> #define FLT_DIG                6
> ```

Question: if the standard allows `DBL_MAX == 1E+37` and `DBL_MIN == 1E-37` (i.e. properties of `double` == properties of `float`), then why it requires `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG >= 10` and `DBL_DIG >= 10` (and not `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG >= 6` and `DBL_DIG >= 6`)?

P.S. Maybe I miss something. Please point the right direction.

Comment: For the same reason that the standard allows `int` == `long` but requires `LONG_MAX >= 214783647` even though it requires `INT_MAX >= 32767`.

Comment: I think you are confounding required *range* of floating point types with required *precision* of floating point types. (And it is not limited to IEEE formats.)

Comment: @IanAbbott C does not allow `LONG_MAX == INT_MAX == +32767`. However, as I see, C allows `DBL_MAX == FLT_MAX == 1E+37`. The same for `_MIN`.

Comment: C *does* allow `LONG_MAX == INT_MAX` and `LONG_MIN == INT_MIN`, and there are several common implementations where that is the case. For example MS Windows and 32-bit Linux. EDIT: You are correct that it does not allow `LONG_MAX == 32767`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, indeed,  _C does allow LONG_MAX == INT_MAX and LONG_MIN == INT_MIN_. I was correcting my comment while you were answering it.

Comment: C also allows `FLT_DIG == 10` (and `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG == 10`). Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If C standard allows "double == float", then why it requires DBL_DECIMAL_DIG and DBL_DIG >= 10 (and not >=6)?

The conditions that `double` **may** be identical to `float` and `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` ≥ 10 and `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` ≥ 6 are consistent because they are satisfied by a format used for both `double` and `float` such that `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` = 10 and `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` = 10.

The condition that `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` ≥ 6 is not superfluous, because the conditions are satisfied by one format used for `double` such that `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` = 10 and another format used for `float` such that `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` = 6.

(`DBL_DIG` and `FLT_DIG` are not discussed above but are analogous.)

> Question: if the standard allows `DBL_MAX == 1E+37` and `DBL_MIN == 1E-37` (i.e. properties of `double` == properties of `float`), then why it requires `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG >= 10` and `DBL_DIG >= 10` (and not `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG >= 6` and `DBL_DIG >= 6`)?

`DBL_MAX` and `DBL_MIN` speak to the exponent range. `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` and `DBL_DIG` speak to the precision. These are not directly related; an exponent range may be chosen independently of a precision and vice-versa.