# Code output explanation

Tags: c, io

**Question 1.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

  int c;
  while((c=getchar())!='\0')
   {
     putchar(c);
   } 
}
```

**Input**

> Hello C.
>
> Tell me about you.

**Output**

> Hello C.
>
> Tell me about you.
>
> ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

and it continues with status-time limit exceeded.

**Question 2.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  float a;
  a=46.43253;
  printf("\n%d",a);
  printf("\n%f",a);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> 536870912
>
> 46.432529

Comment: Try `EOF` instead of `'\0'`

Comment: Replacing '\0' with    EOF     works the same.

Comment: What happens if you test against `'\n'`?

Comment: The first snippet works fine for me with `EOF`.

Comment: Ask ***one*** question, not two unrelated ones. Please do not add a third question, ask a new one.

Comment: Try using `\n` instead of `\0`. It's better practice to use new line character than null terminator.

Comment: `a=46.43253;` This is not Right. What is `a` and what is `46.43253` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Output-  536870912
>
> 46.432529

In general using incorrect format specifier triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - which is what you have when you use `%d` in printf for printing float. In this case, you can expect any output usually.

However, it may also be the case that since you have specified to read the float number as integer (e.g. by using `%d` specifier), it simply interpreted the result as integer - hence the strange number (since floats and integers are stored differently).

If you are interested why the second printf prints a number slightly different from yours, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value) may help you.

Comment: `a=46.43253;` This is not right because `a` is FLOAT. What is `46.43253` ?

Comment: @Michi Sorry? didn't follow you.

Comment: @Michi Are you saying `46.43253` is not a float?

Comment: What's the difference between 46.43253 and 46.43253f?

Answer (score 0):

This block is fine:

```
float a;
a=46.43253;
```

This block is also fine:

```
printf("\n%f",a);
```

The problem is with this block:

```
printf("\n%d",a);
```

Particularly this part:

```
"\n%d"
```

Please keep in mind you declared a float and using the integer syntax to output it. That's why you are getting the negative output
If it is a case where you don't want to change the "%d," then simply cast it as a float before output