# Rounding floats in C

Tags: c, floating-point

While testing the float type and printing it with it's format specifier `%f` I was testing it's rounding methods.

I've declared the variable as float and gave it the value 5.123456. As you know float must represent at least 6 significant figures.

I then changed it's value to 5.1234567 and printed the value with the `%f`. It baffles me why it prints out as 5.123456. But if I change the variable value to 5.1234568, it prints out as 5.123457. It rounds properly.

If I haven't made myself clear or the explanation is very confusing:

```
float a = 5.1234567
printf("%d", a); 
// prints out as 5.123456

float a = 5.1234568
printf("%d", a); 
// prints out as 5.123457
```

I've compiled using CodeBlocks and MinGW, same result.

Comment: The exact value of 5.1234567f is 5.123456478118896484375 which clearly should round down when rounded after the 6.

Comment: "at least 6 significant figures" doesn't mean 6 digits after the decimal point. You're trying to get 7 or more digits of precision out of a float.

Answer (score 4):

OP is experiencing the effects of [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding)

First, the values 5.123456, 5.1234567, etc. are *rounded* by the compiler to the closest representable `float`.  Then `printf()` is *rounding* the `float` value to the closest 0.000001 decimal textual representation.

---

> I've declared the variable as float and gave it the value 5.123456. As you know float must represent at least 6 significant figures.

A `float` can represent about 2^32 different values. 5.123456 is not one of them.  The closest value a typical `float` can represent is 5.12345600128173828125 and that is correct for 6 *significant* digits: 5.12345...

```
float x = 5.123456f;
//  5.123455524444580078125 representable float just smaller than 5.123456
//  5.123456                OP's code
//  5.12345600128173828125  representable float just larger  than 5.123456 (best)

// The following prints 7 significant digits
// %f prints 6 places after the decimal point.
printf("%f", 5.123456f); // --> 5.123456
```

---

With 5.1234567, the closest `float` has an exact value of 5.123456478118896484375.  When using `"%f"`, this is expected print rounded to the closest `0.000001` or `5.123456`

```
float x = 5.1234567f;
//  5.123456478118896484375 representable float just smaller than 5.1234567 (best)
//  5.1234567                OP's code
//  5.1234569549560546875   representable float just larger  than 5.1234567

// %f prints 6 places after the decimal point.
printf("%f", 5.1234567f); // --> 5.123456
```

---

Significant digits is *not* the number of digit after the decimal point.  It is the number of digits starting with the left-most (most significant) digit.

To print a `float` to 6 significant figures, use `"%.*e"`.
See [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359) for more details.

```
float x = 5.1234567;         
printf("%.*e\n", 6 - 1, x);  // 5.12346e+00
                             // x xxxxx   6 significant digits
```

Comment: I haven't seen decimal to floating-point to decimal round-trips characterized as "double rounding" before. Usually it is described as successive roundings in the same base -- no conversion involved. I think the simpler answer is just that [floats do not have 8 digits of precision in that range](http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/).

Comment: @RickRegan  Double rounding, even when in the same base, is effectively a _conversion_ from some internal high precision to a lower one.  The same principal applies here even though a change in base is also involved.    Suggest you post the alternative "floats do not have 8 digits of precision in that range." as an answer.  For me, I find the link insufficient as it explains half of the round trip and not the whole round trip issues experienced by OP.

Comment: Actually the article does cover the full round-trip, though more implicitly than explicitly. That's not to say it's a better answer than yours (more of a supplement?). It's mainly your characterization of the conversion as a rounding that I disagree with; 5.1234567 becomes 5.123456478118896484375 (the 7 becomes 478118896484375) -- is that a (decimal) rounding per se?

Comment: @RickRegan As I see it: the conversion of source code text "5.1234567", which has an exact  _value_ of 5.1234567 which has a binary value of `101.0001_1111_1001_1010_1101_1011_1011...` to a `float` incurred a _binary_ rounding to 24-bits: `101.0001_1111_1001_1010_1101_1`.  That `float`'s binary value is exactly 5.123456478118896484375.  Thus the first rounding.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact float representation for the number 5.1234567 you intend to show here.

If you check here: 
https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

You can see that this number is converted into 5.1234565, or the double 5.1234564781188965 and this rounds down,

While the number 5.1234568 is representable in float, and has a double representation of 5.123456954956055, and this rounds up.

Answer (score 0):

There are two levels of rounding going on:

1. Your constant of 5.1234567 gets rounded to the nearest value which can be represented by a float (5.123456478...).
2. The float gets rounded to 6 digits when printed.

It will become obvious if you print the value with more digits.

What it comes down to is that the mantissa of a float has 23 bits and this is not the same as 6 decimal digits (or any number of digits really). Even some apparently simple values like 0.1 don't have an exact float representation.