# Force printf to display a determined number of digits and remove remaining 0s

Tags: c, printf, precision

I don't figure out how to tell printf to print a double with a variable precision.

Where is what I actually do :

```
int main(void)
{
    int digits = 4;

    printf("%0.*f\n", digits, 0.123456789);
    printf("%0.*f\n", digits, 5.9);

    return (0);
}
```

I actually have the variable precision with the * and the digits variable, but it still prints remaining 0 after the last number.

In order to illustrate my problem, here is what i get :

```
0.1234
5.9000
```

And here is what i want :

```
0.1234
5.9
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `%g` instead of `%f`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int digits = 4;
    printf("%0.*g\n", digits, 0.123456789);
    printf("%0.*g\n", digits, 5.9);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.1235 
5.9
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/csf8lD)</kbd>

Comment: I already tried this, but it doesn't works very well, if I test with digits = 29
I got this output :

    1.2345678899999998900938180668

Comment: @ChrisProlls that is because the exact number is `0.12345678899999999733605449137030518613755702972412109375`. This is the nearest `double` number to `0.123456789`.

Comment: @ChrisProlls-- also note that a `double` does not have 29 digits of precision.

Comment: @DavidBowling I know, but I don't want to let any bug or usable breach, this why I asked if it's possible to print the float with a maximum precision, without add more digits than the float have.

Comment: I thought that you asked to "print a double with a variable float precision."

Comment: @ChrisProlls Little need to print a `double` with more than `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` (typically 17) significant digits.  [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359).

Comment: I wasn't aware of some behaviours that float and double shares. Here is a good document to understand floating point precision in computer programming, that every beginner should read > [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)