# fopen a file and skip character

Tags: c, printf, fopen

Is there a clean way to open a file like this without system calls:

```
ID*_LogConfig.csv
```

I tried the following but it didn't worked.

```
/*Read setup file*/
getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
snprintf(source, sizeof(source),"%s/ID%*d_LogConfig.csv",cwd);
if( NULL == (input = fopen(source,"r")))
{
    snprintf(errbuffer,sizeof(errbuffer), "Could not open file %s - check existence/rights\n", source);
    exitHandler(1, errbuffer);
}
```

It outputs:

```
/mnt/dataflash/canfilter.d/ID*_LogConfig.csv not found
```

But with e.g. cat /mnt/dataflash/canfilter.d/ID*_LogConfig.csv it shows the file content.

My compromise solution would be a system call `ll ID*_LogConfig.csv` and using the output as filename.

Comment: `ll` is not a system call. It's a program invoked by the shell. It's also the shell the preforms glob substitution.

Comment: Does not `%*d` expect a width and `int` argument?  Try `snprintf(source, sizeof(source),"%s/%s", ,cwd, "ID*_LogConfig.csv");`

Comment: What is `cwd`? what is `source`? what is `errbuffer` ? please add the definitions for these to your question.

Comment: Is the file actually named `ID*_LogConfig.csv` If it is, you spelled `ID%*d_LogConfig.csv` wrong in your snprintf  call, it should be just `ID*_LogConfig.csv` . But perhaps you mean that the asterisk expands to something else, perhaps a number or a date/timestamp?  This is extremely important to your question. Please write `ls -l /mnt/dataflash/canfilter.d/ID*_LogConfig.csv`  so we can know exactly what your file(s) are named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a clean way to open a file like this without system calls

No.
`fopen()` makes use of a system call. You cannot 'open' a file without a system call.

If you're referring to the [`system(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function, then you're probably in for some pain - it's best to avoid it if possible, from a performance, reliability and security point of view.

If you want to open 'all files that match the pattern', then look at [`glob(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob), which is likely what your shell is using to handle such wildcards.
You will need to iterate over each of the resulting paths, calling `fopen()`, `fread()` and `fclose()` on each.

Example usage of `glob(3)`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glob.h>

void main(void) {
    int ret;
    int i;
    glob_t glob_info;

    ret = glob("*.csv", 0, NULL, &glob_info);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "glob() failed: %d\n", ret);
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < glob_info.gl_pathc; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, glob_info.gl_pathv[i]);
    }

    globfree(&glob_info);
}
```

---

It is not really a good idea to open lots of files and treat the stream as a single 'thing' (as you are doing with your `cat` example).

As @Andrew has pointed out, you *must* be careful with your use of `printf()` format strings...
You have provided the following: `%s/ID%*d_LogConfig.csv`. A `%` denotes the beginning of a format specifier, you have thus given the following:

- `%s` - a `char *` (string) parameter follows
- `%*d` - similar to `%d`, but the `*` means that the precision is provided as an `int` parameter, followed by the number itself.

For example:

```
printf(">%s< >%*d<\n", "Hello", 5, 3);
```

Will output: (note the 5 characters that the `%d` outputs)

```
>Hello< >    3<
```

If you are after a `*`, then just put a `*` in the format string.
If you are after a `%`, then you need to escape the `%` but putting `%%` in the format string.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
snprintf(source, sizeof(source),"%s/ID%*d_LogConfig.csv",cwd);
```

likely does not produce what you think it does.

The `%*d` portion is an format specifier with a field-width, [per the POSIX `printf()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)

> A field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an
>    ( '*' ). In this case an argument of type int supplies the
>   field width or precision. Applications shall ensure that arguments
>   specifying field width, or precision, or both appear in that order
>   before the argument, if any, to be converted. A negative field width
>   is taken as a '-' flag followed by a positive field width. A negative
>   precision is taken as if the precision were omitted. In format strings
>   containing the "%n$" form of a conversion specification, a field width
>   or precision may be indicated by the sequence "*m$", where m is a
>   decimal integer in the range [1,{NL_ARGMAX}] giving the position in
>   the argument list (after the format argument) of an integer argument
>   containing the field width or precision, for example:
>
> ```
> printf("%1$d:%2$.*3$d:%4$.*3$d\n", hour, min, precision, sec);
> ```

So, this line

```
snprintf(source, sizeof(source),"%s/ID%*d_LogConfig.csv",cwd);
```

expects *two* more integer arguments to be passed.  Since you don't pass them, you invoke undefined behavior.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897395/4756299

Answer (score -2):

Ok I solved the "problem" by using the following:
(Processing the output of ls -t and use the newest file as config-file)

```
/*Search for config-file*/
FILE  *file_config;
file_config = popen("ls -t ID*_LogConfig.csv","r");
if (file_config == NULL)  {
    exitHandler(1, "Error opening date pipe.");
}   
fgets(configfile, sizeof(configfile), file_config);
if (strlen(configfile) > 0)
    configfile[strlen(configfile)-1] = '\0';
else {
    exitHandler(1, "Could not find a ID*_LogConfig.csv\n");
}   
getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
snprintf(source, sizeof(source),"%s/%s",cwd,configfile);

/*Read setup file*/
if( NULL == (input = fopen(source,"r")))
{   
    snprintf(errbuffer,sizeof(errbuffer), "Could not open file |%s| - check existence/rights\n", source);
    exitHandler(1, errbuffer);
}
```

It seems that this is the only simple way.

Thanks to all.

Comment: `configfile[strlen(configfile)-1] = '\0';` causes UB when `configfile[0] == 0`.  This is a rare thing by chance, yet can also be a hacker exploit.

Comment: This is not a good solution, and you also appear to have added a requirement **use the newest file as config-file**.