# How can I convert a float to string?

Tags: rust

How can a float value be converted to a String? For whatever reason, the documentation and all online sources I can find are only concerned with the other way around.

```
let value: f32 = 17.65;
let value_as_str: String = .....
```

Comment: And I bet that this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: Aside: In the land of C, printing a `float` to a string with enough, but not too many digits is accomplished with `sprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*e", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, some_float);`.  May provide some ideas for you.

Comment: I actually didn't know about C's ``FLT_DECIMAL``, so thanks for that. C++ has it even nicer with ``std::to_string``; I am looking for something similar to this in rust.

Comment: Note that `std::to_string` uses a fixed (non-exponential notation) that tends to convert a small `float` to "0.000000"  and very large values with excessive digits.  I wonder if `.to_string()` does the same?

Comment: It actually does, at least there at lot of excessive digits; figuring out how to format this will be the next step.

Comment: Converting a `float` to a string (in any language) and retain info about the value  is best done with [exponential notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), else code is attempting to defeat the  "floating" in "floating point".

Comment: I added examples to my answer on how to format using a fixed number of digits after the decimal point as well as how to format using exponential notation.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt The `"3.1415926e6"` does not show how to print pi with an expected value of about `3.1415926e0`.  The other trick is how many digits should be shown to present all `float` uniquely, yet without excessive decimal digits?  Is 8 the right amount - as in your answer?  (it is usually about 9 total digits in C)  I know [how in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897395/2410359), though unfamiliar in Rust, yet the principles are the same.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Sometimes, the answer is easy: [**`to_string()`**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string).

```
let pi = 3.1415926;
let s = pi.to_string();  // : String
```

---

#### Background

The foundation for "creating a readable string representation of something" is in the [`fmt` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html). Probably the most important trait in this module is [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html). `Display` is an abstraction over types that can be formatted as a user-facing string (pretty much exactly what you want). Usually the `Display` trait is used by `println!()` and friends. So you can already convert your float to string with the `format!()` macro:

```
let s = format!("{}", pi);
```

But there is something else: the [`ToString` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/trait.ToString.html). This trait talks about types that can be converted to a `String`. And now, there is a magic implementation:

```
impl<T> ToString for T 
    where T: Display + ?Sized
```

This means: every type which implements `Display` also automatically implements `ToString`! So instead of writing `format!("{}", your_value)` you can simply write `your_value.to_string()`!

While these wildcard implementations are extremely useful and versatile, they have one disadvantage: finding methods is much harder. As you point out, [the documentation of `f32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html) doesn't mention `to_string()` at all. This is not very good, but it is a known issue. We're trying to improve this situation!

#### Advanced formatting

The `to_string()` method uses the default formatting options, so it's equivalent to `format!("{}", my_value)`. But sometimes, you want to tweak how the value is converted into a string. To do that, you have to use `format!()` and the full power of the `fmt` format specifier. You can read about those in the [`module documentation`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html). One example:

```
let s = format!("{:.2}", pi);
```

This will result in a string with exactly **two digits after the decimal point** (`"3.14"`).

If you want to convert your float into a string using **scientific notation**, you can use the `{:e}` (or `{:E}`) format specifier which corresponds to the [`LowerExp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.LowerExp.html) (or [`UpperExp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.UpperExp.html)) trait.

```
let s = format!("{:e}", pi * 1_000_000.0);
```

This will result in `"3.1415926e6"`.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer as soon as I can. Why is this not in the documentation for ``f32``? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html

Comment: @PhilippLudwig I added a bunch of explanation. I hope this clarifies things :)

Comment: That actually does clarify the situation. Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: _Sometimes, the answer is easy_. Well, but the output of e.g. `(1e-300).to_string()` is quite unexpected and different from how stringifying floats works in many other languages. Obtaining a human friendly string actually [does not seem to be straighforward](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59794031/1804173).