# How can I process a string of numbers in Rust?

Tags: string, parsing, rust, numbers, exponential

I have an input:

```rust
let b = String::from("1 2 4 5 6");
```

And my task is to return the exponential function of each value as a string as output:

```rust
let output = "2.718281828459045 7.38905609893065 54.598150033144236 148.4131591025766 403.4287934927351";
```

I have no idea how to solve this task. How to parse each value and use exp function and send string of the result?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the ingredients:

- Split the string: [How do I split a string in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643688/how-do-i-split-a-string-in-rust)
- Convert each part to `f64` (or `f32`): https://programming-idioms.org/idiom/146/convert-string-to-floating-point-number/1974/rust
- Exponentiate each number: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.exp
- Convert results to string: [How can I convert a float to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084968/how-can-i-convert-a-float-to-string)
- Concatenate into single string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41688369

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to repeat what [phimuemue has already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66224989/2766908) so here's an implementation:

```rust
fn example(s: &str) -> String {
    s.trim()
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|n| {
            let mut n = n.parse::<f64>().unwrap();
            n = n.exp();
            n.to_string()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join(" ")
}

fn main() {
    let input = String::from("1 2 4 5 6");
    let output = example(&input);
    dbg!(output); // "2.718281828459045 7.3890560989306495 54.59815003314423 148.41315910257657 403.428793492735"
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cfb15ebe931fea6b64dc5d98fb08e13a)

Comment: Or using [`Itertools::join`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ce539a2fbc815184fe85c1488c84f60e

Comment: It would be more helpful to demonstrate how to propagate the result, rather than `.unwrap()`ing it and potentially panicking on a bad input.