# Shouldn't Float 6 and Double 15 available digits?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I used to think that `float` can use max 6 digit and `double` 15, after comma. But if I print limits [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13249f45ddd095c3):

```
typedef std::numeric_limits<float> fl;
typedef std::numeric_limits<double> dbl;

int main()
{
    std::cout << fl::max_digits10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << dbl::max_digits10 << std::endl;
}
```

It prints `float` 9 and `double` 17?

Comment: 10 binary digits?

Comment: `float can use max 6 digit and double 15, after comma` is incorrect. The precision is 15 digits which counts all the significant numbers, not only the ones after decimal point

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: 15 digit in decimal base? max() on double will print `2.22507e-308` which is way more than 15 digits.

Comment: @markzzz as I said, it's 15 **significant** digits. `2.22507e-308` has only 6

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I'm not following you. If I insert `2.22507e-308` on http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ I got a decimal number with 313 digit after the comma. WAY larger than total 15 :O

Comment: @markzz  313 digits, of which only the first 15 are accurate.  The number 17 includes the period and the sign symbol.

Comment: @markzzz "Significant digit" doesn't mean "digit after the comma".

Comment: If you learn  how a floating point is stored in memory (mantissa + exponent + sign)  you will probably understand it better

Comment: Similar issue in C to [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10):

> Unlike most mathematical operations, **the conversion of a floating-point value to text and back is exact as long as at least max_digits10 were used (9 for float, 17 for double)**: it is guaranteed to produce the same floating-point value, even though the intermediate text representation is not exact. It may take over a hundred decimal digits to represent the precise value of a float in decimal notation.

For example (I am using http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ to facilitate the conversion) and double as the precision format:

1.1e308 => 109999999999999997216016380169010472601796114571365898835589230322558260940308155816455878138416026219051443651421887588487855623732463609216261733330773329156055234383563489264255892767376061912596780024055526930962873899746391708729279405123637426157351830292874541601579169431016577315555383826285225574400

Using 16 significant digits:

1.099999999999999e308 => 109999999999999897424000903433019889783160462729437595463026208549681185812946033955861284690212736971153169019636833121365513414107701410594362313651090292197465320141992473263972245213092236035710707805906167798295036672550192042188756649080117981714588407890666666245533825643214495197630622309084729180160

Using 17 significant digits:

1.0999999999999999e308 => 109999999999999997216016380169010472601796114571365898835589230322558260940308155816455878138416026219051443651421887588487855623732463609216261733330773329156055234383563489264255892767376061912596780024055526930962873899746391708729279405123637426157351830292874541601579169431016577315555383826285225574400

which is the same as the original

More than 17 significant digits:

1.09999999999999995555e308 => 109999999999999997216016380169010472601796114571365898835589230322558260940308155816455878138416026219051443651421887588487855623732463609216261733330773329156055234383563489264255892767376061912596780024055526930962873899746391708729279405123637426157351830292874541601579169431016577315555383826285225574400

Continue to be the same as the original.

Comment: But what is `109999999999999997216016380169010472601796114571365898835589230322558260940308155816455878138416026219051443651421887588487855623732463609216261733330773329156055234383563489264255892767376061912596780024055526930962873899746391708729279405123637426157351830292874541601579169431016577315555383826285225574400` from `1.1e308`?

Comment: As quoted: "It may take over a hundred decimal digits to represent the precise value of a float in decimal notation.". It means that it is impossible to represent `1.1e308` accurately

Comment: :O But I can't store that value into a variable as double. I don't get whats its meaning :O `int` max() is `2147483647`. Easy as this. `double` max() output `1.79769e+308` which I don't get the "value"...

Comment: Between 2 ints, for example: 10 and 12, there is only one number: 11. Between 2 doubles, for example 10.9 and 11.0, there are infinit numbers. So there is a limit (and imprecision) how the underline format can store the number. And what you are seen is exactly this. `1.1e308` is impossible to represent. The best that the underline format can do is the number showed before

Comment: I know. But doubles are "finit". So after some digits it will round to the next/prev. BUT you are still not reply to my question: which (decimal) number is that `1.79769e+308`? If int can store max the (decimal) number `2147483647`, which (decimal) number can store a double?

Comment: It is the max number that you can represent using the IEEE 754 for double representation. Any value greater than that is considered +infinity. You can see here: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF This is the maxinum value that you can represent using this format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158215/discussion-between-markzzz-and-amadeus).

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing `digits10` and `max_digits10`.

If `digits10` is 6, then *any* number with six decimal digits can be converted to the floating point type, and back, and when rounded back to six decimal digits, produces the original value.

If `max_digits10` is 9, then there exist at least two floating point numbers that when converted to decimal produce the same initial 8 decimal digits.

`digits10` is the number you're looking for, based on your description. It's about converting from decimal to binary floating point back to decimal.

`max_digits10` is a number about converting from binary floating point to decimal back to binary floating point.

Comment: See also the handy table "Digit Ranges For Round-Trips To and From IEEE Binary Floating-Point" at the [Exploring Binary](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/) blog.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an exact correspondence between decimal digits and binary digits.

IEEE 754 single precision uses 23 bits plus 1 for the implicit leading 1. Double precision uses 52+1 bits.

To get the equivalent decimal precision, use

> log10(2^binary_digits) = binary_digits*log10(2)

For single precision this is

> 24*log10(2) = 7.22

and for double precision

> 53*log10(2) = 15.95

See [here](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/float/) and also the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) which I don't find to be particularly concise.