# Proper way to convert a double to string without allocating more memory than required?

Tags: c, string, double

I'm wondering what the proper way is too convert a double of unknown value <strike>size</strike> to a string without allocating too much memory. Is there any way to figure out the count of digits in a double? I don't want to allocate too much or too less memory.

Comment: With [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) you can first get the length of the representation. The first 2 parameters should be `NULL` and 0 respectively.  Also note that `snprintf` is found in  POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, C99, so you should compile with `-std=c99`

Comment: How many MByte are you talking about? What do you mean with allocating?

Comment: I so wish POSIX had standardized [`asprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html), and all these nice POSIX extensions included in C11. No such luck, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NULL` as the first argument of [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) to get the size:

> C99 allows str to be NULL and gives the return value (as always) as
>   the number of characters that would have been written in case the
>   output string has been large enough.

And then `malloc`:

```
int main(void)
{
    double num = 3.14;
    size_t len;
    char *str;

    len = (size_t)snprintf(NULL, 0, "%f", num) + 1;
    str = malloc(len);
    snprintf(str, len, "%f", num);
    puts(str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `"%f` with values like 1.23456e-20 result in an uninformative "0.000000"

Answer (score 4):

Here you have a basic example of how to use `snprintf` when you only want to
know the length of the representation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.15lf", M_PI);
    char *pi = malloc(size + 1);
    sprintf(pi, "%.15lf", M_PI);

    printf("PI: '%s'\n", pi);

    free(pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For maximum precision (if you care about precision rather than the style of output), you should change that to `int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, M_PI); char *pi = malloc(size + 1); sprintf(pi, "%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, M_PI);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott nice trick, I didn't know about that (to be fair I haven't read the whole `printf` man page). I didn't want to have maximum precision, I just wanted to have a very long representation.

Comment: @IanAbbott Minor: `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1` is sufficient to form the string and convert back to the same `double` with `"%.*e"`.  Of course an extra digit is not bad.  `"%.*g"` is always a bit trickier.  `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` may/may not  be needed there.

Answer (score 0):

> Proper way to convert a double to string without allocating more memory than required?

Use `snprintf()` to determine the character count need.

```
double value = foo();
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, some_format, value);
if (size < 0) Handle_encoding_error(); // This is very rare
else {
  char *buffer = malloc(size + 1u);
  if (buffer == NULL) Handle_OOM_error(); // This is also rare
  else {
    snprintf(buffer, 0, some_format, value);
    puts(buffer);
    free(buffer); 
  }
}
```

What format to use depends on coding goals. `"%f"` often results in many uninformative digits for large values and  `"0.00000"` for about half of all `double` as many are wee values less than 0.0000005 in magnitude.

A good way to print a `double` with significant digits employ exponential notation.  What is great about using exponential notation is not only is the `double` fully expressed, it maximum string size need can be pre-calculated (about 28) and is not excessive.

By printing with exponential notation and   *precision* of `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1`, code does not need more digits to "round-trip" the string back to the same `double` with `strtod()` or `sscanf()`.

```
"%a"    // Hexadecimal signicand
"%.*e"  // Decimal

int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%a", value);
// or 
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1, value);

// or directly with minimal extra space
//         -   d   .    dddddd                 e   -  expo \0
#define N (1 + 1 + 1 + (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1) + 1 + 1 + 6 + 1)
char buf[N]; 
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1, value);
```

See [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)