# printf behaviour in C

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I am trying to understand what is the difference between the following:

```
printf("%f",4.567f);
printf("%f",4.567);
```

How does using the `f` suffix change/influence the output?

Comment: What is the difference you observe?

Answer (score 5):

> How using the 'f' changes/influences the output?

The `f` at the end of a floating point constant determines the type and can affect the value.

---

`4.567` is floating point constant of type and precision of `double`.  A `double` can represent exactly typical about 2<sup>64</sup> different values.  `4.567` is not one on them<sup>*1</sup>.  The closest alternative typically is exactly

```
4.56700000000000017053025658242404460906982421875     // best
4.56699999999999928235183688229881227016448974609375  // next best double
```

`4.567f` is floating point constant of type and precision of `float`.    A `float` can represent exactly typical about 2<sup>32</sup> different values.  `4.567` is not one on them.  The closest alternative  typically is exactly

```
4.566999912261962890625  // best
4.56700038909912109375   // next best float
```

When passed to `printf()` as part of the `...` augments, a `float` is converted to `double` with the same value.

So the question becomes what is the expected difference in printing?

```
printf("%f",4.56700000000000017053025658242404460906982421875);
printf("%f",4.566999912261962890625);
```

Since the default number of digits after the decimal point to print for  `"%f"` is 6, the output for both rounds to:

```
4.567000
```

---

To see a difference, print with [more precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359) or try `4.567e10, 4.567e10f`.

```
45670000000.000000 // double
45669998592.000000 // float
```

Your output may slightly differ to to quality of implementation issues.

---

<sup>*1</sup> C supports many floating point encodings.  A common one is [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  Thus typical floating-point values are encoded as an *sign * binary fraction * 2<sup>exponent</sup>*.  Even simple decimal values like 0.1 can not be represented exactly as such.