# What does the width represent in float?

Tags: c

I currently learning the C programming language and I am not sure of what the width in a float is?

I have changed the precision of the float already and it added `0` after the `.` and when I changed the value of the width it just added blank spaces behind

```c
    new_price = price + increase;
    printf("New price is %4.2f", new_price);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of this program, and the output created when running it?

Comment: The "_width of a float_" (which is a number if bits) is not the same thing as the "_width field of a floating point format specifier_" (which relates to the number of characters output, and is in any case associated with a `double` in any case).  What is it about the documentation that is unclear? "_Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces._".

Comment: It does what you asked it to do.  What we can't see is what you want it to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value)

Comment: when in doubt, read [`printf` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: Sidenote: You should never use binary floating point types to store monetary values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `4` in `"%4.2f"` is the *width*.  It directs `printf()` to add spaces per:

> If the converted value has fewer characters than the
>   field width, it is padded with spaces (by default) on the left ...