# How to set the level of precision for the decimal expansion of a rational number

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out the decimal expansion of a rational number in C. The problem I have is that when I divide the numerator by the denominator I lose precision. C rounds up the repeating part when I don't want it to.

For example, 1562/4995 = 0.3127127127... but in my program I get 1562/4995 = 0.312713. As you can see a part of the number that I need has been lost.

Is there a way to specify C to preserve a higher level of decimal precision?

I have tried to declare the result as a double, long double and float. I also tried to split the expansion into 2 integers seperated by a '.'

However both methods haven't been successful.

```
int main() {
    int numerator, denominator;
    numerator = 1562;
    denominator = 4995;

    double result; 
    result = (double) numerator / (double) denominator;
    printf("%f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be 1562/4995 = 0.3127127127... but the actual output is 1562/4995 = 0.312713

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value). It may give you some ideas.

Comment: Look into https://gmplib.org/

Comment: Specifying a `float` as `0.3127127127...` most likely won't be accurate.  A `float` most often only has 7 decimal digits of precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%f` format specifier to `printf` shows 6 digits after the decimal point by default.  If you want to show more digits, use a precision specifier:

```
 printf("%.10f\n", result);
```

Also, the `double` type can only accurately store roughly 16 decimal digits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your output format, like this:

```
printf("%.10lf\n", result);
```

Note two things:

1. The value after the `.` specifies the decimal **precision** required (10 decimal places, here).
2. Note that I have added an `l` before the `f` to **explicitly** state that the argument is a `double` rather than a (single-precision) `float`.

EDIT: Note that, for the `printf` function, it is not strictly necessary to include the `l` modifier. However, when you come to use the 'corresponding' `scanf` function for input, it's absence will generate a warning and (probably) undefined behaviour:

```
scanf("%f", &result); // Not correct
scanf("%lf", &result); // Correct
```

Comment: The `l` flag is invalid in this case.  A  `float` passed to a variadic function is implicitly promoted to `double`.

Comment: @dbush isn't `result` actually a `double` as per the question?

Comment: @dbush Unnecessary, yes; invalid, no! But it's good IMHO to get used to specifying explicit formats.

Answer (score 0):

If printing is all you want to do, you can do this with the same long division you were taught in elementary school:

```
#include <stdio.h>


/*  Print the decimal representation of N/D with up to
    P digits after the decimal point.
*/
#define P   60
static void PrintDecimal(unsigned N, unsigned D)
{
    //  Print the integer portion.
    printf("%u.", N/D);

    //  Take the remainder.
    N %= D;

    for (int i = 0; i < P && N; ++i)
    {
        //  Move to next digit position and print next digit.
        N *= 10;
        printf("%u", N/D);

        //  Take the remainder.
        N %= D;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    PrintDecimal(1562, 4995);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me this, I never thought of doing it this way and it's really clever