# How to convert a float value in an array of character

Tags: c

How can i copy a `float` value to an array of characters in c? For example the `float` variable `x = 1.234` is copied to an array of `char` to become `{‘ 1’ , ‘.’ , ‘2’ , ‘3’ , ‘4’}`

Comment: Converting it or copying it in a new array of character

Comment: Use `sprintf(arr,"%f",x)`, with a large enough `arr`.

Comment: Real simple: [sprintf(buff, %f", 1.234)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)

Comment: `"%f"` results in `"0.000000"` or `"-0.000000"` for about half of all possible `double`.  Do not use that to preserve information about the `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `snprintf` over `sprintf`, it address many risk of buffer overflow, when the developer underestimate the required size, or the input is not fully validated.

```
   int status = snprintf(arr, sizeof(arr), "%.3f", val) ;
   ... Check overflow if needed ...
   if ( status >= sizeof(arr) ) {
       .. Overflow
   }
```

printf, like few other functions in the original stdio (gets, vsprintf) rely on the programmer to create large enough buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your `float` number to `string` by using `sprintf()` function, such as:

```
char fnum_str[num]; // num is an integer number which large enough
int slen = sprintf(fnum_str,"%f",fnum); // fnum is your float number
```

Now, your number is converted to `char` array in a separate characteristic `fnum_str`. And you can access to the value by using `fnum_str[i]`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to preserve all the information of a `double` into a *string*,
Use a wide enough string and `s*printf()` with the `%a`, `%e`  or `%g` format specifiers.  These use textual *floating point* representation.  Do not use `"%f"` (textual fixed point) which is uninformative with small values and too verbose with large ones.

```
#include <float.h>
//                    -       hex digits         .   p   -  expo \0
#define DBL_HEX_SIZE (1 + (DBL_MANT_DIG + 3)/4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 8 + 1)
char s[DBL_HEX_SIZE * 2];  // No need to be stingy on buffer sizes.

snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%a", some_double);
```

or in decimal

```
#include <float.h>
//                    - digit .   dec digits            e   -  expo \0
#define DBL_DEC_SIZE (1 + 1 + 1 + (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1) + 1 + 1 + 8 + 1)
char s[DBL_DEC_SIZE * 2];  // No need to be stingy on buffer sizes.

snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1, some_double);
```

Details in [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)