# How to write a floating point array to a file in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I have an `float` array, that has 189 elements (running from index 0 to index 188). I'm having trouble writing this array out to a file. Suppose the first element is 45.6, and the second element is 67.9, I want my output file to look like this:

```
0, 45.6
1, 67.9
```

and so on. I've tried the function shown below, and the result is my output file has odd characters in it.

```cpp
void writeCorrelationToFile(float slidingCorrelator[])
{  
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("CorrelationResult.txt","w");
    printf("inside writeCorrelationToFile, writing out array using fwrite  \n");
    fwrite(slidingCorrelator,4,sizeof(slidingCorrelator),fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I get an output file like this:

```
�'���۽l^��(���!>
```

I have also tried setting `sizeof(slidingCorrelator)` to 189, but that also did not help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fwrite()` function writes binary data. What you want to write is *the human readable (i.e. text) representation of your `float` values*, not the binary representation.

You can do this using `fprintf()`:

```
float slidingCorrelator[N];
FILE *fp;

// ... fill the array somehow ...

fp = fopen("CorrelationResult.txt", "w");
// check for error here

for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d, %f\n", i, slidingCorrelator[i]);
    // check for error here too
}

fclose(fp);
```

Don't forget to check the return value of those functions to detect errors. For more information, see:

- [`man 3 fwrite`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3p.html)
- [`man 3 fprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html)
- [`man 3 fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3p.html)

Comment: To insure successfully reading the same value, especially large and small values, see [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897395/2410359)

Comment: Thanks so much Marco...I was struggling on that for quite a few hours.