# Double function returns a float value

Tags: c, double

```
double to_decimalIEEE754(char *str)
{
    int n = strlen(str);
    double exp = 0;
    double significand = 0;
    double sign = ((char)str[0] - '0') ? -1 : 1;
    for (int i = 1, j = 11, k = 12, counter1 = 0, counter2 = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i >= 1 && i <= 11)
        {
            exp += ((char)str[j] - '0') * pow(2, counter1);
            counter1++;
            j--;
        }
        else
        {
            significand += ((char)str[k] - '0') * pow(2, -counter2);
            counter2++, k++;
        }
    }
    significand += 1;

    return significand * sign * pow(2, exp - 1023);
}
...
// In the real code this is in main obviously
printf("Insert the number you want to convert: ");
scanf("%s", str);
double res = to_decimalIEEE754(str);
printf("%lf\n", res);
```

I use the 64 bit IEEE conversion, the result i get when i put the binary is correct, but it only has float precision when i print it and i don't know why.

Comment: Aside: Cast `(char)` not needed.

Comment: @Rango, note that `to_decimalIEEE754()` does not correctly covert subnormals, zeroes and not-a-numbers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you mean checking input errors?

Comment: No, I mean wrong conversion.  What result do you get with `to_decimalIEEE754("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000") == 0.0`?  For me, the function return value is 1.11254e-308, which is not the hoped for zero.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica are you sure? I ran it with 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 and it gives me 0, also what do you mean by subnormals and NaNs?

Comment: @Rango "it gives me 0"  --> what is _it_?  If _it_ is `printf("%d\n", to_decimalIEEE754("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000") == 0.0);` then good, as that shows the function returning the wrong answer.  If _it_ is `printf("%lf\n", to_decimalIEEE754("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")`, then the output is not 0, but 0.000000 and is a rounded printing of the return value.  Use a better specifier as in `printf("%g\n", to_decimalIEEE754("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"));`.

Comment: @Rango "what do you mean by subnormals and NaNs" --> [subnormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number#IEEE) and [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ure right i print it with .16f and it gave me 0 but with g it gives 1.11254e-308, I think its because the significand is never 0 because i add 1 to it at the end of the loop, so maybe an if statement like `if (significand == 1) {
return 0;
}` could work, also I read about subnormals, and since i read they slow the process so much should i disable them or are there other ways to treat them?

Comment: @Rango, `if (significand == 1) { return 0; }` will fail when the result should be 2,4, 8, ...  Code needs to examine `exp`,  when it is 0, do something special to handle zeroes and subnormals.  When it is max, do something to handle infinity and NANs.

Comment: should i disable them --> no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("%lf\n", res);` prints with a *fixed* precision of 6 decimal places after the decimal point.  This occurs if the argument passed is `float`, `double` or any finite value.  The `l` is optional.

[Typical `double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) needs up to 17 *significant* <sup>*1</sup>decimal digits to distinguish it from other `double`.

Use:

```
printf("%.17g\n", res); // Assumes common double
printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, res); // Portable, uses exponential for large and tiny values
printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1, res); // Portable, always uses exponential notation.
printf("%a\n", res); // Portable, yet in hex
```

See [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)

---

<sup>*1</sup> *significant* is the number of leading decimal digits where the first one is non-zero, regardless of the location of the decimal point. 12345678901.234567 and 0.00012345678901234567 both have 17 *significant* decimal digits.

Comment: @Rango, To check `res = to_decimalIEEE754()` correctness, use `printf("%a %.17g\n", res, res);`.

Answer (score 2):

The `%f` format specifier prints 6 significant digits by default.  If you want to print more, you need a add a precision specifier.  Also, the `l` modifier has no effect when printing, since a `float` can't be passed to a variadic function like `printf`.

```
printf("%.16f\n", res);
```