# Why does the optimizer remove my code?

Tags: c++, optimization

Today I stumbled across a weird problem. Consider this simple program where I try to emulate [MMX's `PADDW` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_226.html):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    uint64_t a = 0;
    uint64_t b = 0x1234123412341234;

    uint64_t c = 0;
    uint16_t *a_words = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&a);
    uint16_t *b_words = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&b);
    uint16_t *c_words = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&c);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
        c_words[i] = a_words[i] + b_words[i];

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a_words[0], a_words[1], a_words[2], a_words[3]);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", b_words[0], b_words[1], b_words[2], b_words[3]);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", c_words[0], c_words[1], c_words[2], c_words[3]);
    printf("%016llx\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this and running with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test && ./test` results in following:

```
0 0 0 0
4660 4660 4660 4660
4660 4660 4660 4660
1234123412341234
```

However, if I enable `-O2`, it displays wrong value (on `-O1` it still works):

```
0 0 0 0
4660 4660 4660 4660
4660 4660 4660 4660
0000000000000000
```

**Why is that?**

---

Other observations:

1. If I unroll the loop, compiling with `-O2` works (!!):

   ```
   #include <cstdint>
   #include <cstdio>

   int main()
   {
       uint64_t a = 0;
       uint64_t b = 0x1234123412341234;

       uint64_t c = 0;
       uint16_t *a_words = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&a);
       uint16_t *b_words = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&b);
       uint16_t *c_words = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&c);

       c_words[0] = a_words[0] + b_words[0];
       c_words[1] = a_words[1] + b_words[1];
       c_words[2] = a_words[2] + b_words[2];
       c_words[3] = a_words[3] + b_words[3];

       printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a_words[0], a_words[1], a_words[2], a_words[3]);
       printf("%d %d %d %d\n", b_words[0], b_words[1], b_words[2], b_words[3]);
       printf("%d %d %d %d\n", c_words[0], c_words[1], c_words[2], c_words[3]);
       printf("%016llx\n", c);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. If I work with very similar problem but for 32-bit integers instead of 64-bit ones, it works as well:

   ```
   #include <cstdint>
   #include <cstdio>

   int main()
   {
       uint32_t a = 0;
       uint32_t b = 0x12121212;

       uint32_t c = 0;
       uint8_t *a_words = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&a);
       uint8_t *b_words = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&b);
       uint8_t *c_words = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&c);

       for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
           c_words[i] = a_words[i] + b_words[i];

       printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a_words[0], a_words[1], a_words[2], a_words[3]);
       printf("%d %d %d %d\n", b_words[0], b_words[1], b_words[2], b_words[3]);
       printf("%d %d %d %d\n", c_words[0], c_words[1], c_words[2], c_words[3]);
       printf("%08x\n", c);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

The problem recurs on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines. Tried `g++ (GCC) 4.9.2` on Cygwin and `g++ (Debian 4.9.1-19) 4.9.1` on GNU/Linux.

Comment: You violate strict aliasing, which results in undefined behaviour, which your compiler exploits.

Comment: Have you tried fno-strict-aliasing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958633/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-horror-stories

Comment: It works with `-fno-strict-aliasing`, thank you! However, judging from the tone of your comments I feel I'm doing the whole thing totally wrong. Mind giving me a clue how could I tackle the problem in a more elegant way?

Comment: @rr- Yes, breaking strict aliasing is totally wrong. Consider `memcpy()` or better yet, `std::copy()` for extracting bytes from an object and putting it into an object of incompatible type.

Comment: In this case, you could use the good old SWAR addition: `((a & 0x7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF) + (b & 0x7FFF7FFF7FFF7FFF)) ^ ((a ^ b) & 0x8000800080008000)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is strict aliasing violation. You write values of type A to memory which stores object of type B. C++ standard says you can't do that (the exception to this rule are `char` and its `unsigned` and `signed` variant)

This is non-portable code, but yet, if you still want to do it legally, what can you do about it?

- copy from `uint64_t` to `uint16_t` array (by `memcpy` or `std::copy`), modify the values, copy it back.
- OR use compiler intrisics which translate directly to vectorized instructions
- OR disable strict aliasing.

Comment: @rr- C++ says no, C says yes (as far as I remember)

Comment: @Yakk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined