# What happens when a C preprocessor macro is defined twice?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I define a macro twice as follows:

```
#define a 2  
#define a 3
```

I thought any occurrence of `a` in the code would be replaced by `2`, and when `#define a 3` is encountered there are no more `a`s are available in the code to be replaced by `3`, so the `2` would take precedence.

But when I executed it `a` was replaced by 3, why?

Comment: Isn't that a warning ? and Can you explain why do you wan't to define such case precisely.

Comment: yes its a warning. I  jus wanted to know how this would  work.

Answer (score 12):

If you define a macro twice like that, the compiler should at least give you warning, if not an error. It is an error.

> §6.10.3/2 : An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be redefined by another `#define` preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical.

You can redefine a macro by explicitly removing the previous definition:

```
#define a 2
/* In this part of the code, a will be replaced with 2 */
...

#undef a
#define a 3
/* From here on, a will be replaced with 3 */
...
```

Macro replacement happens as the file is read, using the macro definitions active at that point in the file, *except* inside (most) preprocessing directives.

> §6.10/7: The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro expansion unless otherwise stated.
>
> §6.10.3.5/1: A macro definition lasts (independent of block structure) until a corresponding `#undef` directive is encountered or (if none is encountered) until the end of the preprocessing translation unit.

Answer (score 7):

`a` will not be replaced by 2 in `#define a 3` as this is also a pre processor.

After processing `#define a 2`, the value of `a` is 2, but it is overwritten by the next statement `#define a 3`

Comment: Yes, you're right, but IMHO you need to expand your answer a bit more to be suitable for this particular question.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear to me what you were expecting to see.

The second line overrides the definition of `a` from the first line.

Any `a` encountered after that will be replaced by `3`.

Comment: my doubt was does " #define a 2 "  will replace " a "  by 2 in the line " #define a 3"  as well as in other part of the code .Hence the second macro definition will become " #define 2 3"  . now "2" is replaced by 3. Is this how it works

Comment: No, the name of a `#define`-d macro is *never* expanded in the definition