# Why to replace static function as object-like macro, #define STATIC static?

Tags: c, macros

I just spotted this in the legacy code. I know that using the macro, whenever the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro. They are most commonly used to give symbolic names to numeric constants.What I know is preprocess has no notion of type safety, scope.

What is the real benefit of doing like this?

```
#define STATIC static
STATIC function1() { /*Do something*/ }
```

I knew that static functions are visible only in that module or translation unit. Not visible outside of the C file they are defined.

---

Why not just declare like this, instead of macro replacement?

```
static function1() { /*Do something*/ }
```

I thought I will find an answer in SO but I didn't find any proper answer.

Comment: This is usually done with macros that have different replacements depending on options you use when compiling, so it might not always expand into the same thing.

Comment: Maybe this question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398612/why-only-define-a-macro-if-its-not-already-defined/32398697#32398697

Comment: @Barmas, in that case, it just overrides the scope of the function that is static when compiling?

Comment: You can change *all* the functions by changing to `#define STATIC` (empty replacement) and suddenly they are not static anymore. If that is a benefit or not is questionable.

Comment: Windows does this a lot define `char *` to `PCHAR` define `int` to `INT` and all, I think its just for readability

Comment: @qwn The PCHAR define is terrible, it should be a typedef.  For example, `PCHAR a, b;` is *very* misleading, since `a` will be `char *` but `b` will be `char`.

Comment: Indeed. The Windows "hungarian notation" has been heavily criticized, one of the main reasons why, is that they hide pointers behind typedefs. Note that this is a coding style originating from early 90s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no rational reason why you would do this. Generally it is bad practice to hide keywords behind `#define` in this manner, because the code turns cryptic and harder to read.

I would *suspect* it has to do with coding style, it is common to write various function specifiers in upper case, particularly in Windows programming. Often it is done to specify a certain calling convention. For example CALLBACK in Windows, or this example from the old "Windows bible" (Petzold):

```
#define EXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
```

(Which could be modified to also contain `extern "C"` in case of C++.) You'd then have a function such as `EXPORT void CALLBACK func (void)`. Similarly there's also `WINAPI` in Windows.

Sometimes we also see things like

```
#define PRIVATE static
```

which is kind of horrible, because `static` doesn't really have the same meaning as `private` in C++.

Comment: sometimes `inline` during the debugging is replaced with nothing. So replacing `inline` with nothing is sometimes handy. Same with long attributes `PACKED` is easier to read than `__attribute__((__packed__))`. Capital letters usually indicate the macro.

Comment: @Lundin, true I felt its bad practice to do that, harder to read the code.