# Type dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rule

Tags: c

I have a compiler warning ('type dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rule') in this code:

```
volatile uint8_t Buff[READ_BUFF_SIZE];

#define   LD_DWORD(ptr)      (DWORD)(*(DWORD*)(BYTE*)(ptr))

ChunkID = LD_DWORD(&Buff[0]); <-- here is warning
```

I am on 32 bit Cortex M0.

Despite the warning, it is working fine. My question is, can the warning be solved?

Comment: Read about *strict aliasing* rule. It's a broad subject.

Comment: ...did you try pasting the warning into your favourite search engine? or this very site?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958633/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-horror-stories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinterpreting objects that don't have allocated storage duration as objects of some other (incompatible) type is undefined behavior.

In your example `Buff`which has type `uint8_t` which has either static or automatic storage duration, is being reinterpreted as type `DWORD`. Those type are not compatible<sup>1</sup>, the behavior is not defined.

You should simply define `Buff` as type you intend to use, which appears to be `DWORD`:

```
volatile DWORD Buff[READ_BUFF_SIZE];
```

and then you don't need macros for access, simply using the built-in operator will do:

```
ChunkID = Buff[0];
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Even if we assume<sup>2</sup> uint8_t is defined as unsigned char, which may alias any type, the type `DWORD` may not alias `unsigned char`.

<sup>2</sup> Standard permits that the type `uint8_t` is not defined as `unsigned char` even if CHAR_BIT is 8. See extended integer types.

Comment: Yeah, it's a decent answer — but it doesn't make the question less of a duplicate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Only 'decent'? :-) Yeah I guess it's 'kinda' a dup.

Comment: Ok, got'it and make sense! I always want to know why are warnings generated. Thanks for links, I read some and understood. I cannot declare my buffer as other than uint8 since there are many routines that use it as is. But in several others, data makes sense as uint16, uint32 etc. I solve it more ellegant by using unions on original buffer. Thanks.

Comment: @user1797147 You could use malloc. Allocated memory is more flexible.