# Is it possible to write to an array second element by overflowing the first element in C?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, nasm

In low level languages it is possible to `mov` a dword (32 bit) to the first array element this will overflow to write to the second, third and fourth element, or `mov` a word (16 bit) to the first and it will overflow to the second element.

How to achieve the same effect in c? as when trying for example:

```
char txt[] = {0, 0};
txt[0] = 0x4142;
```

it gives a warning `[-Woverflow]`

and the value of `txt[1]` **doesn't change** and `txt[0]` is set to `0x42`.

How to get the same behavior as in assembly:

`mov word [txt], 0x4142`

the previous assembly instruction **will set** the first element `[txt+0]` to `0x42` and the second element `[txt+1]` to `0x41`.

### EDIT

What about this suggestion?

define the array as a single variable.

```
uint16_t txt;
txt = 0x4142;
```

and accessing the elements with `((uint8_t*) &txt)[0]` for the first element and `((uint8_t*) &txt)[1]` for the second element.

Comment: `*(uint16_t*)txt = 0x4142;`

Comment: In C you can use a `union` for type-punning like that. In both C and C++ you can use `memcpy`. I'm not sure if casting like shown in the comment by @Jester doesn't break strict aliasing, and the rules for such casting may be different in C and C++ (so please pick *one* programming language).

Comment: @Jester Will it work in terms of endian and data align?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `(uint16_t*)txt`, at a minimum, is an issue due to alignment concerns.

Comment: @Jester `*(uint16_t*)txt = 0x4142;` is a strict-aliasing violation and UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I believe it would be a strict aliasing violation.  The address didn't start out as that of a `uint16_t`.

Comment: Yeah it's bad. But given the type already, and the equivalent x86 instruction, that's basically what it is. Sure you can achieve the same thing with a `union` but that would need changing of the type. `memcpy` would also work but that also doesn't match the assembly which does not copy memory.

Comment: While the Jester's code is UB generally, on x86 platform ("nasm" tag) the endianness and alignment are not an issue for `uint16_t` type (could be issue for 64+ bit types, then `memcpy` from well defined constant is safer, but overall the OP is requesting non-C like feature, so he must expect some UB/breakage of strict C rules.

Comment: The -Woverflow represents the fact that a `char` cannot represent the value `0x4142` (at least on your target system).    The value `0x4142` will be converted to `char` BEFORE doing the assignment.   If `char` is `unsigned` the conversion will use modulo arithmetic to produce a value in the range that a `char` can represent.   The assignment `txt[0] = 0x4142;` therefore does not affect `txt[1]`.   If `char` is `signed`, the result of the conversion is undefined behaviour.    In short, there is no defined way that an assignment `txt[0] = some_integral_value` changes `txt[1]`.

Comment: @peter Perhaps not UB when "If char is signed", but _implementation-defined_.   Details: C11 §6.3.1.3 3.  Still the overall comment is  good.

Answer (score 8):

If you are totally sure this will not cause a segmentation fault, **which you must be**, you can use [memcpy()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm)

```
uint16_t n = 0x4142;
memcpy((void *)txt, (void *)&n, sizeof(uint16_t));
```

By using [void pointers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/void-pointer-c/), this is the most versatile solution, generalizable to all the cases beyond this example.

Comment: the cast to void is not needed

Comment: It illustrates a point. OP probably wants knowledge, not a case specific solution.

Comment: @MartinChekurov *the cast to void is not needed* Given the question is also (currently) tagged C++, it may be.

Comment: @MartinChekurov indeed.

Comment: In the specific example yes, since the size of `n` is known not to overflow. Generally, better force the argument to safe known sizes.

Answer (score 2):

`txt[0] = 0x4142;` is an assignment to a `char` object, so the right hand side is implicitly cast to `(char)` after being evaluated.

**The NASM equivalent is `mov byte [rsp-4], 'BA'`**.  Assembling that with NASM gives you the same warning as your C compiler:

```
foo.asm:1: warning: byte data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
```

---

**Also, modern C is *not* a high-level assembler**.  C has types, NASM doesn't (operand-size is on a per-instruction basis only).  Don't expect C to work like NASM.

C is defined in terms of an "abstract machine", and the compiler's job is to make asm for the target CPU which produces the same *observable results* **as if** the C was running directly on the C abstract machine.  Unless you use `volatile`, actually storing to memory doesn't count as an observable side-effect.  This is why C compilers can keep variables in registers.

And more importantly, **things that are undefined behaviour according to the ISO C standard may still be undefined when compiling for x86**.  For example, x86 asm has well-defined behaviour for signed overflow: it wraps around.  But in C, it's undefined behaviour, so compilers can exploit this to make more efficient code for `for (int i=0 ; i<=len ;i++) arr[i] *= 2;` without worrying that `i<=len` might always be true, giving an infinite loop.  See **[What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)**.

Type-punning by pointer-casting other than to `char*` or `unsigned char*` (or `__m128i*` and other Intel SSE/AVX intrinsic types, because they're also defined as `may_alias` types) violates the strict-aliasing rule.  `txt` is a char array, but I *think* it's still a strict-aliasing violation to write it through a `uint16_t*` and then read it back via `txt[0]` and `txt[1]`.

Some compilers may define the behaviour of `*(uint16_t*)txt = 0x4142`, or *happen* to produce the code you expect in some cases, but you shouldn't count on it always working and being safe other code also reads and writes `txt[]`.

Compilers (i.e. C implementations, to use the terminology of the ISO standard) are allowed to define behaviour that the C standard leaves undefined.  But in a quest for higher performance, they choose to leave a lot of stuff undefined.  **This is why compiling C for x86 is *not* similar to writing in asm directly**.

Many people consider modern C compilers to be actively hostile to the programmer, looking for excuses to "miscompile" your code.  See the 2nd half of this answer on [gcc, strict-aliasing, and horror stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958633/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-horror-stories/2959468#2959468), and also the comments.  (The example in that answer is safe with a proper `memcpy`; the problem was [a custom implementation of `memcpy` that copied using `long*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958633/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-horror-stories/2959468#comment79247919_2959468).)

---

**[Here's a real-life example of a misaligned pointer leading to a fault on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64)** (because gcc's auto-vectorization strategy assumed that some whole number of elements would reach a 16-byte alignment boundary.  i.e. it depended on the `uint16_t*` being aligned.)

---

Obviously if you want your C to be portable (including to non-x86), you must use well-defined ways to type-pun.  In ISO C99 and later, writing one union member and reading another is well-defined.  (And in GNU C++, and GNU C89).

**In ISO C++, the only well-defined way to type-pun is with `memcpy` or other `char*` accesses, to copy object representations.**

Modern compilers know how to optimize away `memcpy` for small compile-time constant sizes.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void set2bytes_safe(char *p) {
    uint16_t src = 0x4142;
    memcpy(p, &src, sizeof(src));
}

void set2bytes_alias(char *p) {
    *(uint16_t*)p = 0x4142;
}
```

Both functions [compile to the same code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+set2bytes_safe(char+*p)+%7B%0A++++uint16_t+src+%3D+0x4142%3B%0A++++memcpy(p,+%26src,+sizeof(src))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+set2bytes_alias(char+*p)+%7B%0A++++*(uint16_t*)p+%3D+0x4142%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.53145760062525,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g81,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dsandybridge',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:31.135209066041426,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dsandybridge',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) with gcc, clang, and ICC for x86-64 System V ABI:

```
# clang++6.0 -O3 -march=sandybridge
set2bytes_safe(char*):
    mov     word ptr [rdi], 16706
    ret
```

Sandybridge-family doesn't have LCP decode stalls for 16-bit `mov` immediate, only for 16-bit immediates with ALU instructions.  This is an improvement over Nehalem (See [Agner Fog's microarch guide](http://agner.org/optimize/)), but apparently `gcc8.1 -march=sandybridge` doesn't know about it because it still likes to:

```
    # gcc and ICC
    mov     eax, 16706
    mov     WORD PTR [rdi], ax
    ret
```

---

> define the array as a single variable.
>
> ... and accessing the elements with `((uint8_t*) &txt)[0]`

Yes, that's fine, assuming that `uint8_t` is `unsigned char`, because `char*` is allowed to alias anything.

This is the case on almost any implementation that supports `uint8_t` at all, but it's theoretically possible to build one where it's not, and `char` is a 16 or 32-bit type, and `uint8_t` is implemented with a more expensive read/modify/write of the containing word.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to Trust Your Compiler(tm) and just write proper code.

With this test code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char txt[] = {0, 0};
    txt[0] = 0x41;
    txt[1] = 0x42;

    std::cout << txt;
}
```

Clang 6.0 produces:

```
int main() {
00E91020  push        ebp  
00E91021  mov         ebp,esp  
00E91023  push        eax  
00E91024  lea         eax,[ebp-2]  
char txt[] = {0, 0};
00E91027  mov         word ptr [ebp-2],4241h    <-- Combined write, without any tricks!
txt[0] = 0x41;
txt[1] = 0x42;

std::cout << txt;
00E9102D  push        eax  
00E9102E  push        offset cout (0E99540h)  
00E91033  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (0E91050h)  
00E91038  add         esp,8  
}
00E9103B  xor         eax,eax  
00E9103D  add         esp,4  
00E91040  pop         ebp  
00E91041  ret
```

Comment: +1, but note that gcc6 and earlier don't do store coalescing (https://godbolt.org/g/HZqFLK).  ICC18 also compiles it to two separate byte stores.  gcc7/8, clang, and MSVC all get it right, though.  But note that this is only the same as `memcpy` from `0x4142` on a little-endian target like x86.  But it's more likely that you know what order you want the bytes in memory, so this is probably an advantage for this code and a disadvantage for `memcpy`, though!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to do a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) which you'll need to use a loop to accomplish (or a function that does the loop for you internally: [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)).

Simply assigning `0x4142` to a `char` will have to be truncated to fit in the `char`. This should throw a warning as the outcome will be implementation specific, but typically the least significant bits are retained.

---

In any case, if you know the numbers you want to assign you could just construct using them: `const char txt[] = { '\x41', '\x42' };`

---

I'd suggest doing this with an initializer-list, obviously it's on you to make sure the initializer list is at least as long as `size(txt)`. For example:

```
copy_n(begin({ '\x41', '\x42' }), size(txt), begin(txt));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/WJMuwJ)

Comment: `char txt[] = { '\x41', '\x42' };` also requires knowledge about the endian.  Given x86 (implied by NASM tag) being little endian, OP may want the opposite order.

Comment: @chux No? Characters have no endianness. If you're saying that the OP may have intended `const char txt[] = { '\x412, '\x41' }`, then yes I assume he would be able to write that?

Comment: My comment was based on " first element [txt+0] to 0x42 and the second element [txt+1] to 0x41",  and `char txt[] = { '\x41', '\x42' };` unnecessarily shows   the opposite.

Comment: @chux OK yeah I got what you're saying. I view this question as a little strategically questionable. Conversion from a larger integer type to a `char[]` seems like the difficult way to do this. I've updated my answer to include a suggestion to use an `initializer_list` which will not suffer from endian ambiguities, and will be platform independent.