# Return "data type" in C

Tags: c, types, return

I want to have a simple

```
something Data() {
    return int;
}
```

or use char, long ... w/e

How would I go about this?

I don't want to return a number, or a string, I want to return the data type

Another option I have tried is using a macro

```
#define Data int
```

and using different ifs and elses, I could use that instead, but I can't use pointers in the macros, so that's a problem as well (I need to return the data type based on a number saved in a pointer).

Here is the exact problem I have, and what I have done so far:

```
//Read/write any type from memory
#define MemRead(type, offset) (*((type*)(memory + (offset))))
#define MemSet(type, offset, value) (*((type*)(memory + (offset))) = (value))

//Get the index for type (0 - char, 1 - short, 2 - int ...)
#define TypeIndex (MemRead(unsigned short, 0) % 4)
//#if TypeIndex == 0
//#define TYPE char
//#elif TypeIndex == 1
//#define TYPE short
//#endif

//#define TYPE SOMETHING HERE maybe an if-else ...
//#if TypeIndex == 0 doesn't work, because I can't use * in macros

char *memory = NULL;

void memory_init() {

    memory = (char*)ptr;

    //Create a list of pointers
    int numOfPointers = 1, tsize = size - 3 * IntSize - START;
    while (tsize > 64) {
        tsize /= 4;
        MemSet(int, numOfPointers++ * IntSize - 3, 0);
    }

    int typeIndex = 0;
    if (size < power(2, (sizeof(short) * 8) - 1)) {
        typeIndex = 1;
    }
    else if (size < power(2, (sizeof(int) * 8) - 1)) {
        typeIndex = 2;
    }
    else {
        typeIndex = 3;
    }

    MemSet(unsigned char, 0, numOfPointers * 4 + typeIndex);
    MemSet(int, HEADER - IntSize, 0);

    int memAvailable = size - HEADER - 3 * IntSize;
    setBoundaries(HEADER + IntSize, memAvailable, memAvailable);
    MemSet(int, size - IntSize, 0);

    //Set beginning pointer
    MemSet(int, HEADER - IntSize, HEADER + IntSize);

    //Set pointers inside the free block
    MemSet(int, HEADER + IntSize, NULL);
    MemSet(int, HEADER + 2 * IntSize, HEADER - IntSize);
}


int main() {

    char region[500];
    memory_init(region, 500);
}
```

I get some memory space, set the first char to be an index showing what data type I will be using and how many pointers there will be on lists (each list contains different sized free blocks), and I can't get to get the type from TYPE.

I could possibly use a switch in each function to work with different data types based on the first index in memory, but that's something ugly and a reason why I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @SMAEL Functions either return objects or have the return type void.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you think you need to be able to return a type? Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Re "*I don't want to return a number, or a string, I want to return the data type*", There's no such thing. "Data type" is not a type of value, so you can't declare a function as returning a value of type "data type", and a value of type "data type" can't be returned.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the problem is described in previous comment
I know I could just use switches inside every function, but that would mean make it a couple times bigger, which I don't want. If I could get a data type from macro or function, it would mean adding only a couple of lines, instead of couple hundred

Comment: Whatever compression you think you are getting by having a "dynamically sized" integer will probably be offset by the extra byte you use to keep track of its size. Just store size as a `size_t` (unsigned int or long) and be done with it.  Otherwise, it's a micro-optimization with a lot of complexity to work correctly.

Comment: @selbie I have that already done. The size for dynamical headers would require only one more byte, and would could save 6 bytes / block.
Also, I would get bonus points for this useless addition, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered and just used the int system

Comment: Short answer: use an enum and convert with switch statements.

Comment: @selbie that's pretty much just using the switches alone, and would not help with anything.

Comment: Please show us which problem you like to solve. Add some source code by [edit]ing your question, please, don't add anything down here in the comments. I don't understand your motivation.

Comment: @thebusybee okay, edited, added some parts of the code which should be enough to show the problem.

Comment: In general, `*((type*)(memory + (offset)))` is a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and will result in [misligned accesses](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7).  Both result in undefined behavior.  [Failures can happen even on x86 systems.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment)

Comment: wait, you mean like aligned in memory, meaning that an int wouldn't be stored in positions 4, 1, 2, 3 etc, right ? instead should be 1, 2, 3, 4
Well, this was kind of a ... part of the assignment, to be able to store even weird-sized blocks, so ... yeah.
It worked the couple dozen times I tested it without any errors or warnings, so not sure about that now. Might confront my lector with this, but I think they'll want me to do it the "misaligned" way.
Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Again, [it can blow up even on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment). *but I think they'll want me to do it the "misaligned" way.*  Those that **can't do**, teach, then?  Because such code [**WILL** blow up on other systems](https://www.google.com/search?q=sigbus+arm+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am really sorry for not being able to (yet) fully understand what you are trying to say here.
BUT, whenever the MemRead is called with a type, I am sure that I have written a value of that type to that place before with MemSet.
That code is also only working on an enclosed array initialized in the beginning (see main on the bottom) (not sure if that helps).

Comment: The problem is that code such as `*((type*)(memory + (offset)))` is fundamentally broken.  It violates the C language requirement not to access memory as a type it is not (strict aliasing) - that's undefined behavior.  It also potentially violates hardware alignment requirements - that's also undefined behavior.  The fact that it has worked for you up until now does not mean it's correct code.  It's like walking through a minefield and not getting blown up - you were lucky, that's all. If you try that code on hardware (such as ARM) that has stricter alignment requirements, it **WILL** blow up.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That brings me to a thought, if I were to retype (cast?) the pointer, would that solve the problem ? Let's say something like: *((type*)memory + (differentOffset)) would that be okay ? It will leave me with a differently structured memory - I could only store ints at every sizeof(int)th position, but would that be the RIGHT way to go?

Comment: (cont)  If someone is actually teaching you to write C code like that, saying things like, "It works, so it's OK!", then in my opinion that person does not understand C and really shouldn't be teaching it.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790815/4756299) quotes the parts of the C standard that such code violates.  If you have to copy memory like that, you need to use `memcpy()`

Comment: *That brings me to a thought, if I were to retype (cast?) the pointer, would that solve the problem ?*  No, because that would still violate strict aliasing even if you account for the alignment.  Since violating that is undefined behavior, compilers can and do assume it won't happen.  [Read some of these answers as to what compilers can do to you if you break strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958633/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-horror-stories).

Comment: @AndrewHenle wait, does this go towards writing in numbers (chars, shorts, ints ...) as well ? Or is it only for strings, because I have never used a string in the whole code. If it's for any type, I am afraid, that what I have done was the proposed solution I had received (cast the list with offset to your desired type, and then set/write in the number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of trying to get a macro on the type, I can just use function which will write the desired number in whatever type the flag is set  to:

```
void MemRead(int offset) {
    switch(flag something something) {
        case 1 //for char
        case 2 //for short etc etc
    }
}
```

Easy as that

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want without a selecting `switch` or equivalent construct. In C the data types can not be passed around like in example in Java. There is no reflection. C++ has RTTI which might help, or templates but using them will generate all needed machine code behind the curtain. And you clearly asked for a C solution. C is kind of a low-level language compared with its successors.

You best bet will be a function that receives all necessary parameters and sets the appropriate amount of memory.

Under the hood those languages, which support what you want, will dispatch to different code, too, I'm sure. You just don't need to write all the lines.

You could also code the *size* of the memory in the first byte. But please be aware that the access to the following bytes will not be aligned. And some architectures don't allow this, and you will experience run-time errors.

How about using a union? The compiler will make sure that your data types are correctly aligned.

```
typedef enum {
    T_CHAR, T_SHORT, T_INT,
} TYPE;

typedef struct {
    TYPE t;
    union {
        char c;
        short s;
        int i;
    }
} ENTRY;

void memory_init(ENTRY* memory) {
    // prepare as you like
    switch (memory.t) {
    case T_CHAR:
        memory.c = value;
        break;
    case T_SHORT:
        memory.s = value;
        break;
    case T_INT:
        memory.i = value;
        break;
    default:
        // error handling...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: TBH, I don't see how this is not basically the solution with a switch in each function (which I am trying to avoid (it's possible, but not really nice)).
Added some more code to show, that I only use the MemSet and MemRead, so it would be copying the whole code a couple of times for each data type

Comment: On a low level, you right, it works similarly. But as others and me already said, you're calling for disaster because of UB, if you try to manage memory the way you show us. -- My answer includes *some* hints, and a type safe proposal, that's the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will look into the memory alignment issue, and confront my lecturer about it.
SO, there is no real way to do it my nice (but alignment wise wrong) way, right ?
(adding the if I tried to get working as well)

Comment: Well, even if you got it to work with your current set of compiler and target, and let's assume that you find a standard conforming way, it will still be hackish and hard to grasp. Nothing a young padawan should learn to do if s/he strives to reach mastery. ;-) Source code is mostly read by humans, and these should understand your intentions. Trust the compiler to do the best it can to translate it to optimal machine code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I might understand what you wanted to say in a year or two, but not now, that's for sure.
I guess I will just not get the couple bonus points instead for now (or do my ugly switch everywhere solution).
Again, thanks for your engagement in trying to help me to a solution I didn't know I needed, but which should be better.