# Returning 16-bits given a pointer in C

Tags: c

A chunk is represented by a 64-bit long integer, which is broken into 4 16-bit sections.

I need to return a 16-bit section using the function below.

```
unsigned short get_16bitsection(unsigned long *start, int index) {
// Fill this in 
}
```

Comment: Is all that bashing around to try and handle endian issues?

Comment: I get that, but I'm asking about byte order. Is this presuming little-endian or big-endian architecture?

Comment: Yes is not an answer to "big" or "little".

Comment: Well, which one? lol

Comment: What does `index` represent here? Which "section" you want?

Comment: Why is `start` a pointer? That's very misleading. You could just pass in a value.

Comment: p = start;  p = p + (3-index) ;  your confusion stems from understanding of pointer arithmetic. Incrementing pointer makes it to point next address based on its datatype. For example p is pointer of type int ( 2 bytes) and points to address 0x1200 then incrementing pointer makes it to point to 0x1202

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point here but it could be as easy as this:

```
unsigned short get_16bitsection_be(unsigned long *start, int index) {
  unsigned short *p = (unsigned short*) start;

  return p[3 - index];
}

unsigned short get_16bitsection_le(unsigned long *start, int index) {
  unsigned short *p = (unsigned short*) start;

  return p[index];
}
```

Where the difference between [big and little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is relevant here.

Note you should consider using [`stdint.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) to give these types more meaningful names and make it clear what you're actually doing:

```
uint16_t get_16bitsection_le(uint64_t *start, int index) {
  uint16_t *p = (uint16_t*) start;

  return p[index];
}

uint16_t get_16bitsection_be(uint64_t *start, int index) {
  uint16_t *p = (uint16_t*) start;

  return p[3 - index];
}
```

You were on the right track with your second approach, but that code is heavily cluttered by a lot of things that don't matter, plus the `* 8` offset which makes no sense.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217508/discussion-on-answer-by-tadman-returning-16-bits-given-a-pointer-in-c).

Answer (score 4):

It is tempting to use casts to achieve this, but it is a common misconception that "everything is just bytes" and thus that you can do that safely. [A rule called *strict aliasing* actually prohibits doing so.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/4386278) Your code may appear to work, particularly on older and less sophisticated compilers, but in the age of heavy optimisations you are really playing with fire by violating the language rules like that.

Instead, you should *copy* the bytes you need into a `uint16_t`, then return it:

```
uint16_t get_16bitsection(uint64_t *start, int index) {
  uint16_t result;
  memcpy(&result, (char*)start + index*sizeof(uint16_t), sizeof(uint16_t));
  return result;
}
```

Here I cast to `char*` so that we can navigate byte-wise through your chunk (this aliasing is a specifically permitted exception to the usual strict-aliasing rule), then apply an offset of `index*sizeof(uint16_t)` to reach the desired index (assuming little endian, which you have specified). Finally, we copy the bytes into `result`, and return it.

If you're concerned about performance, don't be. You were already copying a `uint16_t` from local scope into the calling scope; just now it has a name. And if this function *is* any slower than the aliasing-violating version, then that's evidence that you've confused the optimiser into going too far.

Comment: This is an interesting question where the answers list some bad things that can happen when you violate strict aliasing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958633/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-horror-stories  And here's an example of a failure on x86 systems (interestingly enough it involves `unsigned short` aliasing): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790550/c-undefined-behavior-strict-aliasing-rule-or-incorrect-alignment/46790815#46790815  So x86 isn't immune to address alignment restrictions either.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a union.

```
long int x=0x123456789abcdef0;

union {
    long int x;
    unsigned short arr[4];
} c;

c.x = x;
printf("%04x %04x %04x %04x\n", c.arr[0], c.arr[1], c.arr[2], c.arr[3]);
```

Result:

def0 9abc 5678 1234

Comment: Actually I take it back; it could be explicitly valid since C11. I'm a bit behind on C. Still, this requires modifying the declaration of the source data.

Answer (score 0):

> Returning 16-bits given a pointer
> A chunk is represented by a 64-bit long integer, which is broken into 4 16-bit sections

To access the data in a endian independent portable way and retrieve the 0:LS 16-bit to 3:MS 16-bit, use `>>`.

---

As `unsigned long` may only be 32-bit, recommend `unsigned long long` or `uint_least64_t`.
Consider making pointer `const` to allow this function use on `const` data.

```
unsigned short get_16bitsection(const unsigned long long *start, int index) {
  #define MASK_16BIT 0xFFFFu
  return MASK_16BIT & (*start >> (16*index));
}
```

- Mask useful on rare machines where `unsigned short` is not 16 bit. IAC, I prefer mask over casts - gentler way to reduce range.
- Alternatively use a cast: `(unsigned short)` or `(uint16_t)` though this is slightly less portable as `uint16_t` may not exist and `unsigned short` may be > 16-bit.