# QByteArray access and strict aliasing

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

The rules of strict aliasing are mystifying (to me). Is the following code legal or UB?

Assume the buffer comes from a socket, and an `Alias` type wasn't placement-new'ed anywhere within my code.

```cpp
struct Alias
{
  int64_t a;
  int64_t b;
}

int read(const QByteArray& buffer)
{
  Alias* alias = reinterpret_cast<Alias*>(buffer.data());
  int isThisUB = alias.a;
  return isThisUB;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is UB or not because `buffer.data()` returns a `char*`? If it is, does `launder`'ing it make it well defined?

```cpp
int read(const QByteArray& buffer)
{
  Alias* alias = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Alias*>(buffer.data()));
  int isThisUB = alias.a;
  return isThisUB;
}
```

Do I *actually* need to use `memcpy` or some `union` here?

---

Reasons I'm confused:

- https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1307
- [gcc, strict-aliasing, and horror stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958633/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-horror-stories)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/j7gn2d/stdvariant_is_broken_in_clang_and_it_exposes_how/

Comment: `function` isn't a keyword in C++

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili the first part yes. I'm guessing this isn't what `std::launder` is designed to solve?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus: For whatever reason, compiler writers seem opposed to having a "launder" construct with a broad meaning on the basis that it would impede optimization, willfully ignoring the fact that such a construct would make it easy to do things that are otherwise difficult, and that in many such cases, the performance of code with optimization blocked wouldn't be much different from the performance of the most efficient possible code *that would actually accomplish the required task*.  It may be much slower than the useless broken machine code...

Comment: ...that could have been produced without the barrier, but the ability to generate machine code to quickly perform some action that doesn't meet application requirements isn't very useful.