# memcpy boolean to void *

Tags: c, boolean, memcpy, void-pointers

I was just creating a testing function in which i have to pass boolean in void * so that i can parse it in other function and use it.

but i am stuck and not able to know that how should i memcpy the boolean in void *.

but when i am parsing it in another fucntion i am always getting the value true.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    uint8_t var_data[];
} s;

void parse(s * dummy)
{
    void *var_data = dummy->var_data;
    
    uint8_t *len;
    char type[128];
    bool *leaf;
    for(int i = 0; i < dummy->a; i++)
    {
        len = (uint8_t *)var_data;
        var_data += 1;
        memcpy(type, var_data, *len);
        type[*len] = '\0';
        var_data += *len;
        leaf = (bool *)var_data;
        var_data += 1;
        
        printf("%s\n", type);
        printf("leaf: %s\n\n", leaf ? "true" : "false");
    }
}

int main() 
{
    // Write C code here
    char val[] = "dummy value";
    uint8_t len = strlen(val);
    bool v = false;
    int b = 2;
    int sz = sizeof(s) + b * (sizeof(bool) + len + 1);
    s * dummy = (s *) malloc(sz);
    dummy->a = b;
    void *var = dummy->var_data;
    for(int i = 0; i < dummy->a; i++){
        memcpy(var, &len, 1);
        var += 1;
        memcpy(var, val, len);
        var += len;
        memcpy(var, &v, sizeof(bool));
        var += sizeof(bool);
    }
    parse(dummy);
    return 0;
}
```

can body help me with this problem.

Comment: You have a pointer `var_data`, but *where does it point?*

Comment: to some struct's variable data.

Comment: Also, you increase `var_data` after the `memcpy` call, which means that it no longer points to the data you copied to there it pointed. So "in another function" the pointer is not pointing to the data you think it does.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve]. Also please try to explain *why* you need to do it this way. What is the original problem you want to solve.

Comment: Usually you would just cast the bool to a pointer (which isn't a valid pointer and you can't dereference it) and then cast the pointer back to a bool.

Comment: i have not added the completed code because it is too long code but i have parse it accordingly to the structure that i want every value is coming right but in case of boolean eveytime true value is coming.

Comment: A [mcve] isn't supposed to be your "complete code", it's supposed to be enough for us to copy-paste and replicate the problem you ask about and nothing more.

Comment: You original code contained `var_data += sizeof(bool);` at the end, which changes quite a bit. Why did you remove it?

Comment: sorry @Someprogrammerdude Sir i have added the dummy code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't dereference `leaf` in this line:

```
printf("leaf: %s\n\n", leaf ? "true" : "false");
```

Since `leaf` is a non-zero pointer, it will always evaluate to `true` in C. You want to print `*leaf` instead:

```
printf("leaf: %s\n\n", *leaf ? "true" : "false");
```

Some other misc remarks:

1. `void*` arithmetic (i.e. `var_data += 1`) is illegal in C, although gcc will not complain. Use a `char*` because this is the type that's supposed to be used for serialization.
2. As mentioned in other answers, using pointers like you are doing right now can lead to subtle errors. If your pointer is pointing to an address and you want to dereference it (read the value stored there), it's better to do this sooner than risk this location being changed by some other code in the meantime.

   So, just copy the data from the `char*` array into the target struct (or a primitive like `uint8_t`) and then advance the pointer.
3. The only way you are technically allowed to cast pointers in C is to cast them *from* a specific pointer (like `something*`) to a `char*`, in order to inspect their contents. You can also implicitly cast from and to `void*`, but only if you are not aliasing the pointer (trying to modify the underlying type). Any casting in the other direction is a violation of strict aliasing, so you should try to use `memcpy` instead. It may look uglier, but compiler will optimize it anyway ([see for yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/x865an)) and you'll be safe(r) from [the horrors of aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2958633/69809).
4. One nice habit to have it to try to utilize const-correctness wherever you can, it helps the compiler warn you if you're doing something wrong. If your function is parsing the array, the parameter should be `const char*`.
5. Finally, if your goal is to serialize and deserialize structs, perhaps you should look into [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) or some similar serialization framework. It is fast, efficient, portable and, best of all, already written.

So, something like:

```
typedef struct {
    int len;  
    char * var_data;
} example;

// note the const keyword - this means this function is
// not going to change the struct, only read it
void parse(const example * dummy)
{
    // again, pointer to const char
    const char * var_data = dummy->var_data;
    
    // move all variables to the innermost scope
    for (int i = 0; i < dummy->len; i++)
    {
        uint8_t len = 0;
        memcpy(&len, var_data, sizeof(len));
        var_data++;

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay now i get it i did a blunder and will try to remember all the point you have stated sir. Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 3):

`var_data` is uninitialized. You should allocate `var_data` with `malloc`, and copy the data in `leaf` into it:

```
void *var_data = malloc(sizeof(bool));
bool leaf = false;
memcpy(var_data, &leaf, sizeof(bool));
```

And you can cast it to `bool *` like this:

```
bool *leaf;
leaf = (bool *) var_data;
```

In addition, you increment `var_data` pointer. So `var_data` points to a different memory location now.

Comment: Sir i have just not added the malloc peice code here but i have done the same and is showing true even when i have passed the false value.

Comment: @SaranshDixit: If you don't post your exact actual code, people can only guess where the problem is.

Comment: sorry @Groo Sir i have added the dummy code of the problem i am facing